# Django data migration when changing a field to ManyToMany

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I have a Django application in which I want to change a field from a ForeignKey to a ManyToManyField.  I want to preserve my old data.  What is the simplest/best process to follow for this?  If it matters, I use sqlite3 as my database back-end.

If my summary of the problem isn't clear, here is an example.  Say I have two models:

```
class Author(models.Model):  
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100) 

class Book(models.Model):  
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)  
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Say I have a lot of data in my database.  Now, I want to change the Book model as follows:

```
class Book(models.Model):  
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author)  
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I don't want to "lose" all my prior data.

What is the best/simplest way to accomplish this?

Ken

Comment: Check out [south](http://south.aeracode.org/).

Comment: More specifically check out "data migrations" section of the tutorial: http://south.aeracode.org/wiki/Tutorial3

It's a good habit to use South for all your migrations anyway.

Comment: Great tool, thanks for the link!

Comment: if this isn't obvious already, make sure you back up your data before trying any migrations. luckily, copying sqlite is as easy as a `cp` command

Comment: I wonder if there is a bug report about this.

Answer (score 105):

I realize this question is old and at the time the best option for Data Migrations was using South. Now Django has its own `migrate` command, and the process is slightly different.

I've added these models to an app called `books` -- adjust accordingly if that's not your case.

First, add the field to `Book` and a `related_name` to at least one, or both of them (or they'll clash):

```
class Book(models.Model):  
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='book')
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='books')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Generate the migration:

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'books':
  0002_auto_20151222_1457.py:
    - Add field authors to book
    - Alter field author on book
```

Now, create an empty migration to hold the migration of the data itself:

```
./manage.py makemigrations books --empty
    Migrations for 'books':
0003_auto_20151222_1459.py:
```

And add the following content to it. To understand exactly how this works, check the documentation on [Data Migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). Be careful not to overwrite the migration dependency.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models, migrations


def make_many_authors(apps, schema_editor):
    """
        Adds the Author object in Book.author to the
        many-to-many relationship in Book.authors
    """
    Book = apps.get_model('books', 'Book')

    for book in Book.objects.all():
        book.authors.add(book.author)


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('books', '0002_auto_20151222_1457'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(make_many_authors),
    ]
```

Now remove the `author` field from the Model -- it should look like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name='books')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Create a new migration for that, and run them all:

```
$ ./manage.py makemigrations
Migrations for 'books':
  0004_remove_book_author.py:
    - Remove field author from book

$ ./manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: messages, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, sessions, books, contenttypes
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying books.0002_auto_20151222_1457... OK
  Applying books.0003_auto_20151222_1459... OK
  Applying books.0004_remove_book_author... OK
```

And that's it. The authors previously available at `book.author` now should be in the queryset you get from `book.authors.all()`.

Comment: Hey @JanSegre: not really, the many-to-many relationship changes are done the moment you run `.add()`.

Comment: Oh, you're right, thanks. That's what I get for glossing over the docs instead of reading them properly.

Comment: just one suggestion, the query inside a for loop will be slow if run on a large table. using a single-line SQL will be much faster. e.g.    `insert into books_book_authors (book_id, author_id) 
    select id, author_id from books_book;` you can run it with `migrations.RunSQL`

Comment: @kakarukeys That is true, but I wouldn't mention it as a primary way of doing it since it's not database-agnostic.

Comment: it is database-agnostic, as it is in SQL standard, and all db providers have not deviated from the standard syntax, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25971

Comment: @RodrigoDeodoro how would I do that when I want to migrate a ManyToMany field to "through"? When I try your method, I get an error as I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512976/django-migrate-manytomany-to-through

Comment: you can do it in one migration, in `operations` list write commands in this oreder: add_m2m_field, your_function_to_migrate_data, delete_fk_field, rename_m2m_field

Comment: just a note when applying for book in Book.objects.all(): book.authors.add(book.author) -- you may need an if statement i.e. if book.author

Comment: Did something change about this in Django 1.11? I get a null id constraint error using this strategy.

Comment: [This tutorial](https://ponytech.net/blog/convert-foreign-key-many-to-many-using-django-migrations) uses the same technique as this answer, and also includes some extra details such as example data.

Comment: HI @Salvioner, `apps` is not an import, it's an argument that `RunPython` passes to `make_many_authors`. This answer is now 5 years old and I haven't run this code in recent years but in any case the solution for this wouldn't be adding an import.

Comment: @RodrigoDeodoro can you help me on this?? same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68467714/writing-sql-query-in-production-server-for-changing-foriegnkey-field-to-m2m-in-d

Comment: it works perfectly on my local but my aws data are gone

Comment: Hi @Django-Rocks, I'm really sorry your data is gone but I haven't worked with Django in years (this answer is 5 years old) but the first thing I'd tell you to look for are differences between your local and production environments. Good luck!

Comment: @Rodrigo Deodoro, thank you a lot!) I was very afraid, but it worked for me.
For Many-to-Many field I have just deleted on_delete=models.SET_NULL and null=True.

Comment: While `related_name='book'` is technically correct, since it’s different to the other `related_name=books`, it’s misleading, since in the also in the original ForeignKey field an author can have man books, not just one.

Comment: Any chance you would provide the backwards version of this RunPython migration?

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best and easiest thing you should do would be:

Create the Many to many field with a different name say

```
authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
```

write a small function to convert foreignkey values to M2M values:

```
def convert():
    books = Book.objects.all()
    for book in books:
        if book.author:
            li = [book.author.id]
            book.authors.append(li)
            book.save()
```

Once it is run, you can delete the author field from the table and run migration again.

Comment: in django 1.10 i get a `AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'append'`
i removed .id and had `book.authors = li` and that worked. I believe you can also do `book.authors.add(li)` and that should satisfy the issue.

Comment: You can append and save in the models anyway you want. The question and the answer more specifically takes care of the migrations.

Comment: Use `book.authors.add(*li)` if you get `AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'append'`