# How to convert a Foreignkey field into ManyToMany field in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Django data migration when changing a field to ManyToMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224410/django-data-migration-when-changing-a-field-to-manytomany)

how I can accomplish this without losing data? someone know how to do that? thanks to all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [south](http://south.aeracode.org/)