# How to add through option to existing ManyToManyField with migrations and data in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I can't find reference to particular issue in docs or online.

I have an existing many to many relation.

```
class Books(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Authors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Books)
```

This has migrations and data. Now I need to use through option in order to add one extra field in table holding many to many relation.

```
class Authorship(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Books)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Authors)
    ordering = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

class Authors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Books, through=Authorship)
```

When I run migrations, django creates fresh migration for `Authorship` model. I tried to create migration file manually by adding `ordering` column in `Authorship` table and altering `books` column in `Authors` table but I get some migration issues.

```
operations = [
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='authorship',
        name='ordering',
        field=models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1),
    ),
    migrations.AlterField(
        model_name='authors',
        name='books',
        field=models.ManyToManyField(to='app_name.Books', through='app_name.Authorship'),
    ),
]
```

When trying to migrate, it gives `KeyError: ('app_name', u'authorship')` I bet there are other things that are affected and thus errors.

What things am I missing? Is there any other approach to work with this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks  like there is no way to use through option without having to do data migrations. So had to resort to data migration approach, I took some ideas from @pista329's answer and solved the issue using following steps.

- Create `Authorship` model

  ```
    class Authorship(models.Model):
        book = models.ForeignKey(Books)
        author = models.ForeignKey(Authors)
        ordering = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
  ```
- Keep original ManyToManyField relation, but add another field using above defined model as through model:

  ```
    class Authors(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        books = models.ManyToManyField(Books)
        published_books = models.ManyToManyField(
            to=Books,
            through=Authorship,
            related_name='authors_lst' # different related name is needed.
        )
  ```

  **IMPORTANT**: You must use a different `related_name` to the existing ManyToManyField. If you don't do this then Django may lose the data in the original field.
- Add data migration to copy all data from old table to new `Authorship` table.

After this, `books` field on `Authors` model can be removed as we have new field named `published_books`.

Comment: "different related name is needed."!!!!!! This is what I've been looking for!! Why does Django not make it clear that adding a new through relationship with the same (or no) related name will result in relationship data being lost. Thanks for this. You saved me after a full day of painful testing.

Comment: I ended up going with a variation of this but I didn't want to change all my existing tests/code and wanted to be able to remove the migration code via squashing (with `SeperateDatabaseAndState` you can't).  Here's what I ended up doing:

Migration #1: rename field `books` to `temp_books`.  Migration #2: change `temp_books` related_name to `temp_authors`'s. Migration #3: Adding the desired field name back `books` w/ the through table. Migration #4: Custom migration to transfer the data. Migration #5: Removal of `temp_authors` field. 

(MySQL 5.7 and django 3.2.13)

Answer (score 44):

There is a way to add "through" without data migrations.
I managed to do it based on [this @MatthewWilkes' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35463030/1552186).

So, to translate it to your data model:

1. Create the `Authorship` model only with `book` and `author` fields. Specify the table name to use the same name as the auto-generated M2M table you already have. Specify the `unique_together` attribute to match what the auto-generated M2M table does ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L1098)). Add the 'through' parameter.

   ```
    class Authorship(models.Model):
        book = models.ForeignKey(Books)
        author = models.ForeignKey(Authors)

        class Meta:
            db_table = 'app_name_authors_books'
            unique_together = ['book', 'author']

    class Authors(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        books = models.ManyToManyField(Books, through=Authorship)
   ```
2. Generate a migration, but don't run it yet.
3. Edit the generated migration and wrap the migration operations into a `migrations. SeparateDatabaseAndState` operation with all the operations inside `state_operations` field (with `database_operations` left empty). You will end up with something like this:

   ```
    operations = [
        migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(state_operations=[
            migrations.CreateModel(
                name='Authorship',
                fields=[
                    ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                    ('book', models.ForeignKey(to='app_name.Books')),
                ],
                options={
                    'db_table': 'app_name_authors_books',
                },
            ),
            migrations.AlterField(
                model_name='authors',
                name='books',
                field=models.ManyToManyField(through='app_name.Authorship', to='app_name.Books'),
            ),
            migrations.AddField(
                model_name='authorship',
                name='author',
                field=models.ForeignKey( to='app_name.Author'),
            ),
            migrations.AlterUniqueTogether(
                name='authorship',
                unique_together={('book', 'author')},
            ),
        ])
    ]
   ```
4. You can now run the migration and add the extra `ordering` field to your M2M table.

**Edit:**
Apparently, column names in the DB are generated slightly differently for  automatic M2M tables as for models-defined tables. (I am using Django 1.9.3.)

After the described procedure, I also had to manually change the column names of a field with a 2-word name (`two_words=models.ForeignKey(...)`) from `twowords_id` to `two_words_id`.

Comment: Yes, this approach works. for the column name, I just used db_column that match the previous column name.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning this warning from Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/migration-operations/#separatedatabaseandstate) regarding the use of `SeparateDatabaseAndState`: "Do not use this operation unless you’re very sure you know what you’re doing."

Comment: I'm not "very sure I know what I'm doing" so can somebody explain what `SeparateDatabaseAndState` is and what it is doing in this case?

Comment: realpython.com has a nice explanation of SeparateDatabaseAndState in part two of this series: https://realpython.com/django-migrations-a-primer/ (this links to part one, which doesn't cover SeparateDatabaseAndState yet)

Comment: In Django's 3.0 docs they included this specific case: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/writing-migrations/#changing-a-manytomanyfield-to-use-a-through-model using the SeparateDatabaseAndState way. But still the trick of making the migration and then wrapping it with SeparateDatabaseAndState is just awesome, thanks.

Comment: The auto-generated M2M table also adds a unique_together constraint ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L1098)). I've suggested an edit to the answer to include this.

Comment: Thanks @kcontr. I didn't test it, but looks like it makes sense, so edit accepted :)

Answer (score 2):

Migrations can be messy sometimes.

If you want to alter m2m field with through, I would suggest to rename altered field `Authors.books` to `Authors.book`. When asked by `makemigrations`, if you changed name from books to book? `[yN]`, choose "`N`" as No. Django will delete `books` and create `book` field instead of altering.

```
class Authorship(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey("Books")
    author = models.ForeignKey("Authors")
    ordering = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

class Authors(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book = models.ManyToManyField("Books", through="Authorship")
```

If you want to use `books` anyway, change `book` to `books` and repeat migration process with `y` as answer to makemigrations question about renaming.

Comment: This will require data migrations otherwise I will lose existing data, no?

Comment: Yes, since you will remove field. If you dont wan't to loose data, do not remove `books`, just add `book`. Then migrate data from `books` to `book` simply via SQL.