# How to alter the auto created model of a ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: django, django-models, model, many-to-many

I have two Django models Authors and Books. Authors has a reference to Books using a ManyToManyField as:
`books = models.ManyToManyField(Books)`

As per Django's documentation a table will be auto-created for us. How do I alter the id field of this auto-created table from `AutoField` to `BigAutoField`(as I have reached the maximum limit of the table) without losing data or moving the data around, and without running any SQL commands.

**Note:** The model was auto created by Django and not manually defined. A table exists in the database but not a model which can be directly modified by the user. Please correct me if this is wrong. I could not find a solution where we can simply alter the id column of an auto-generated "through" table using Django with the above restrictions.

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40654521 helped. But it involves creating a through model, which does not allow using add, create or set in Django v2.0 and I strongly prefer to use them.

Comment: Anything stopping you from upgrading to a later version of Django? 2.0 is pretty old at this point...

Comment: Yes. This code is running in production and and it just works. To upgrade to a later version of django alongwith python and other dependencies would need some significant testing which we currently cannot perform. Totally agree that it is pretty old.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of to get the `BigAutoField` in the automatically generated tables is with a setting that was introduced in Django 3.2.

```py
# settings.py

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# or in app_name/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class AppNameConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

FWIW, I never use the auto-generated tables from `ManyToManyField`s because I almost always end up customizing them further. It's trivial to inline a form or write a method that handles creation of new intermediate records on demand similar to how Django does it - but considerably more difficult to override Django's internals.

Comment: As per Django 3.2 [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std-setting-DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD) changing the `DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD` does not update the primary key field for the existing auto generated tables but for any new auto generated table only. 

However, that section had some pointers for updating an existing table in the db using migrations, which I am considering.

Comment: @roymurdo Indeed you are correct. I didn't specify that either approach would be a solution to your particular problem since you stipulated that you wanted to do this without "moving the data around, and without running any SQL commands". They're just the two configuration options that I'm aware of that deal with the auto field defaults. A migration would be my recommendation. Though they're a pain to write, they're the most reproduceable way to handle something like this.