# How to set a ManyToMany field to an existing object in a Django migration?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm trying to migrate a 1-to-many field to an **existing** many-to-many field.  I'll explain.

If I understood what was happening exactly, this question would be shorter. However, I'll try to give all the detail in hopes someone will spot the issue.

For migrating a 1-to-many to a new many-to-many, I read [this blog post](https://ponytech.net/blog/convert-foreign-key-many-to-many-using-django-migrations) (also like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224410/django-data-migration-when-changing-a-field-to-manytomany)), which worked.  To summarize:

They started with a 1-to-many model (pizza has one topping):

```
from django.db import models

class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    topping = models.ForeignKey(Topping)
```

and showed the migrations to get from one topping to multiple toppings per pizza.

In the second of three migrations they add a topping to the new many-to-many toppings field in a `forward` method of a migration which looks like this:

```
def forward(apps, schema_editor):
    Pizza = apps.get_model("pizza", "Pizza")
    for pizza in Pizza.objects.all():
        pizza.toppings.add(pizza.topping)
```

However, now I'm trying to migrate a different model to use *the existing toppings*.  `add` isn't right, because I don't want to create new relationships, I want to use existing ones.

This is stretching the pizza example, but suppose I have a note for some pizzas about their topping (I dunno, calories?).  That worked when there was one topping per pizza, but now that there are multiple toppings, I want that note to move to a pizza topping instead of a pizza.  Something like:

```
class Note(models.Model):
  # We're planning to get rid of pizza after copying
  pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza)
  # I named the many-to-many field with a through object called PizzaTopping.
  # null=True because we want to migrate existing values into this field
  topping = db.ForeignKey(PizzaTopping, on_delete=db.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Now I have a migration for Note with:

```
    def forward(apps, schema_editor):
        Note = apps.get_model('pizza', 'Note')
        for note in Note.objects.all():
            # Find the existing pizza toppings for this Note
            # There's only one, since we just migrated pizza topping to toppings
            pizza_topping = PizzaTopping.objects.get(pizza_id=note.pizza)
            note.topping = pizza_topping
```

I get an error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "<PizzaTopping: PizzaTopping object (606)>":
  "Note.topping" must be a "PizzaTopping" instance.
```

That's pretty confusing, those types look the same!  However, I traced this to a line in Django's `related_descriptor.py` in the `ForwardManyToOneDescriptor` object, `__set__` method:

```
        # An object must be an instance of the related class.
        if value is not None and not isinstance(
            value, self.field.remote_field.model._meta.concrete_model):
```

The issue may be that `value` is a `PizzaTopping`, while `self.field.remote_field.model._meta.concrete_model` is a `__fake__.PizzaTopping`.

What is the complication here that introduces `__fake__`?  Is it the ForwardManyToOneDescriptor?  Is it that I'm in a migration?

How do I copy an existing PizzaTopping into my note in this migration code?

Comment: After all that, I may have answered my question.  I used `note.topping_id = pizza_topping_id` and it didn't do any type checking.

Comment: How did you resolve this?

Comment: I used the ids directly, as in my comment above.