# how i insert values from list of Data Grid View?

Tags: c#, ado.net

it show me this error  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select' to make to clear Employee ID in this case is FK in the table (Attendance detail) and the other thing  is  i am using Data Grid View from another table(Employee information) to Show the list of the staff in my form. then i want to transfer each selected cell value from Data Grid View to attendance detail table. 10q

```
    private void time_in_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        employee_InformationDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].Style.ForeColor = Color.Green;

            time_in.Enabled = false;
            time_out.Enabled = true;

            con = new SqlConnection(GlobalClass.conn);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Attendancedetail  Values(" + "Select from  EmployeeInformation(EmployeeID)" + ",'" + employee_InformationDataGridView.SelectedCells[0] + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + "','" + null + "','" + null + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "'," + null + ")", con);
            int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show(i.ToString() + " record inserted");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of your SQL query is wrong. A [`SELECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx) statement requires you to specify the columns you want to return. For example:

```
SELECT EmployeeID FROM EmployeeInformation
```

Comment: 10q for the fast response but it is not work it show me this error  
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.
Incorrect syntax near ''.
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Attendancedetail  Values(" + "Select EmployeeID From EmployeeInformation" + ",'" + null + "','" + null + "','" + null + "','" + null + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "'," + null + ")", con);

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Darin, but the full syntax is

Insert into Attendancedetail **(columns list)** select **columns list** from EmployeeInformation where employeeid = ' selected cells value'

The Values keyword is not used in such a statement. The 1st columns list is optional if the Select returns all needed columns.

See [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from) for more examples

Comment: 10q for the fast response but it is not work it show me this error

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Select'.
Incorrect syntax near ','.
 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Attendancedetail  Values(" + "Select Employee from EmployeeInformation where FullName = ' Selected Cells Value'" + ",'" + null + "','" + null + "','" + null + "','" + null + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + "'," + null + ")", con);

Comment: Remove the the values keyword. Your select is only returning one column, so specify its name after the inserted table name (except if this Attendancedetail table has only one column).
Consider using Management Studio (or whatever client program of your DB) to have the statement correct, then add it to your code.
And follow @Raj's advice of using parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using parameterized queries. Writing code like this will result in sql injection.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html