# Combining INSERT INTO and WITH/CTE

Tags: t-sql, insert, common-table-expression

I have a very complex CTE and I would like to insert the result into a physical table.

Is the following valid?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.prf_BatchItemAdditionalAPartyNos 
(
    BatchID,
    AccountNo,
    APartyNo,
    SourceRowID
)       
WITH tab (
  -- some query
)    
SELECT * FROM tab
```

I am thinking of using a function to create this CTE which will allow me to reuse. Any thoughts?

Comment: Note that the implementation depends on the platform.  Snowflake uses the same syntax as OP’s example (i.e. cte *after* insert).

Answer (score 358, accepted):

You need to put the CTE first and then combine the INSERT INTO with your select statement. Also, the "AS" keyword following the CTE's name is not optional:

```
WITH tab AS (
    bla bla
)
INSERT INTO dbo.prf_BatchItemAdditionalAPartyNos (
BatchID,
AccountNo,
APartyNo,
SourceRowID
)  
SELECT * FROM tab
```

Please note that the code assumes that the CTE will return exactly four fields and that those fields are matching in order and type with those specified in the INSERT statement.
If that is not the case, just replace the "SELECT *" with a specific select of the fields that you require.

As for your question on using a function, I would say "it depends".  If you are putting the data in a table just because of performance reasons, and the speed is acceptable when using it through a function, then I'd consider function to be an option.
On the other hand, if you need to use the result of the CTE in several different queries, and speed is already an issue, I'd go for a table (either regular, or temp).

[WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 37):

The `WITH` clause for Common Table Expressions go at the top.

Wrapping every insert in a CTE has the benefit of visually segregating the query logic from the column mapping.

**Spot the mistake:**

```
WITH _INSERT_ AS (
  SELECT
    [BatchID]      = blah
   ,[APartyNo]     = blahblah
   ,[SourceRowID]  = blahblahblah
  FROM Table1 AS t1
)
INSERT Table2
      ([BatchID], [SourceRowID], [APartyNo])
SELECT [BatchID], [APartyNo], [SourceRowID]   
FROM _INSERT_
```

**Same mistake:**

```
INSERT Table2 (
  [BatchID]
 ,[SourceRowID]
 ,[APartyNo]
)
SELECT
  [BatchID]      = blah
 ,[APartyNo]     = blahblah
 ,[SourceRowID]  = blahblahblah
FROM Table1 AS t1
```

A few lines of boilerplate make it extremely easy to verify the code inserts the right number of columns in the right order, even with a very large number of columns. Your future self will thank you later.

Comment: This is great! All of a sudden, I don't hate INSERT statements as much...

Comment: This is extremely useful. For anyone else who missed it on the first reading, the problem this solves is that in an insert statement the mapping is defined by the relative ordering of the fields to be inserted into and the values to be inserted into them, which are listed separately. If you write these normally it's incredibly difficult to check by visual inspection that the two orderings are the same. The CTE allows you to name the values with the column names that they're going to be inserted into, which means you can align these really nicely on two lines.

Answer (score 22):

Yep:

```
WITH tab (
  bla bla
)

INSERT INTO dbo.prf_BatchItemAdditionalAPartyNos (  BatchID,                                                        AccountNo,
APartyNo,
SourceRowID)    

SELECT * FROM tab
```

Note that this is for SQL Server, which supports multiple CTEs:

```
WITH x AS (), y AS () INSERT INTO z (a, b, c) SELECT a, b, c FROM y
```

Teradata allows only one CTE and the syntax is as your example.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but for my purposes I wanted to be able to run the code the user inputted and store in a temp table. Using oracle no such issues.. the insert is at the start of the statement before the with clause.

For this to work in sql server, the following worked:

INSERT into #stagetable execute (@InputSql)

(so the select statement @inputsql can start as a with clause).