# How to save a queried CTE output into a temporary table or table variable

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression, sql-server-2014, table-variable

I have a `CTE` and query this one

```
;With CTE_Table as (SELECT ...)
Select * from CTE_Table
```

Now I try to save this result into a `table variable` or `temporary table`. If I try

```
Declare @Table table
(...)
INSERT INTO @Table (...)
HER I PUT THE CODE ABOVE
```

I get an `incorrect syntax error` around the `WITH` statement. I guess the `Insert Into` command expects a `Select statement` instead of a `;WITH` and the same goes for `Create Table`. I was looking for solutions but all [I found](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/63725d14-8e59-4009-b1da-c28f96f98d8e/using-a-cte-then-getting-results-into-a-temp-table) did not involve the `Select Statement` after the `;With`. How do I get the output shown above into a `temporary table` or `table variable`?

I use SQL Server 2014.

Comment: The keyword to start a CTE is `with` not  `;with`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Really?

Comment: @Frisbee: yes, see Mikael's answer for a correct usage of the statement _termination_ character

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Terminator is not line dependent.   You can  move it to the "with" line.  ;with is not  keyword. It is a terminator followed by a keyword.

Comment: @Frisbee: I know that. But the constant pattern of writing `;with` apparently makes a lot of people think that a CTE is started by using `;with` see e.g. questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11491240/330315 or this http://stackoverflow.com/q/26670414/330315 and the way this question is written kind give me the impression that ruedi also thinks that a CTE needs to start with `;with`

Comment: the answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938060/common-table-expression-why-semicolon) contains all information about it . There you can find the answer why I used the ; before with. Thanks for the discussion though I should not have used that in this example, it is confusing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name And your inference that ;with is a keyword does not add clarity

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You add the insert statement to the main query right after the CTE declarations.

```
declare @T table(ID int);

with C(ID) as
(
  select 1 union all
  select 2
)
insert into @T(ID)
select ID
from C;

select ID
from @T;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @t table(
Name nvarchar(MAX),
Id bigint
)

;WITH CTE as (
    SELECT 'Name' as Name , 1 as Id
)
INSERT INTO @t(Name,Id)
SELECT Name,Id FROM CTE


SELECT * FROM @t
```