# INSERT INTO temp table with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert into temp table with a `insert into....select`. 
my current statement looks like the following:

```
insert into ods.account
(
  AccountNumber,
  AccountName,
  AccountCreated,
  AccountEnded,
  PayoffDate
)
select
  AccountNumber
  , AccountName
  , AccountCreated
  , AccountEnded
  , PayoffDate 
from dbo.InsuranceAccount
```

I want to be able to put this information into a temp table if possible I would like to insert into temp table at the top of my query in SQL Server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create Temp table with SELECT \* INTO tempTable FROM CTE Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491240/how-to-create-temp-table-with-select-into-temptable-from-cte-query)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
select
  AccountNumber
  , AccountName
  , AccountCreated
  , AccountEnded
  , PayoffDate into #myTempTable
from dbo.InsuranceAccount
```

or you could create your temp table first and then do the insert:

```
create table #tempTable(AccountName varchar(100), AccountNumber int)-- so on..
insert into #tempTable(AccountName, AccountNumber)
select AccountName, AccountNumber from dbo.InsuranceAccount
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can do this using temp tables in SQL.

If you simply just want to insert the contents of a select into a temp table, use the following method. Keep in mind, you cannot use this in a loop because it creates the temp table each time the select runs:

```
select
  AccountNumber
  , AccountName
  , AccountCreated
  , AccountEnded
  , PayoffDate 
into #temp_table      
from dbo.InsuranceAccount
```

You can also pre-define the temp table and then use `INSERT INTO` as you would any other table. This method is good because you can use this kind of temp table in a `WHILE` loop and insert data each loop through.

```
create table #temp_table
(
  field1 int not null,
  field2 char(1),
  ...
)

insert into #temp_table
select 
  AccountNumber
  , AccountName
  , AccountCreated
  , AccountEnded
  , PayoffDate      
from dbo.InsuranceAccount
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('temp..#InsuranceAccount') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE #InsuranceAccount
END

SELECT  AccountNumber
      , AccountName
      , AccountCreated
      , AccountEnded
      , PayoffDate 
INTO  #InsuranceAccount
FROM dbo.InsuranceAccount
```