# Insert Record from CTE to Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. For getting some rows I am using a CTE in my stored procedure.

```
;WITH
CTE AS (
    SELECT   BrokerId ,
                    RankId ,
                    BrokerName ,
                    RankName ,
                    BrokerCode ,
                    IntroducerCode ,
                    CscName ,
                    MAX(SIP) AS SIP ,
                    MAX(Fresh) AS Fresh ,
                    MAX(FY) AS FY ,
                    MAX(SY) AS SY ,
                    MAX(TY) AS TY ,
                    CscId ,
                    Promotive ,
                    NoOfPromotive ,
                    PlanTypeName ,
                    PlanYear
     FROM @tmp
     GROUP BY BrokerId ,
                    RankId ,
                    BrokerName ,
                    RankName ,
                    BrokerCode ,
                    IntroducerCode ,
                    CscName ,
                    CscId ,
                    Promotive ,
                    NoOfPromotive ,
                    PlanTypeName ,
                    PlanYear
)
SELECT  BrokerId ,
        RankId ,
        BrokerName ,
        RankName ,
        BrokerCode ,
        IntroducerCode ,
        CscName ,
        SUM(SIP) AS 'SIP' ,
        SUM(Fresh) AS 'Fresh' ,
        SUM(FY) AS 'FY' ,
        SUM(SY) AS 'SY' ,
        SUM(TY) AS 'TY' ,
        Promotive ,
        Total = ISNULL(( SUM(SIP) ), 0) + ISNULL(( SUM(Fresh) ), 0)
        + ISNULL(( SUM(FY) ), 0) + ISNULL(( SUM(SY) ), 0)
        + ISNULL(( SUM(TY) ), 0) ,
        NoOfPromotive ,
        PlanTypeName ,
        PlanYear ,
        CscId
FROM CTE
GROUP BY BrokerId ,
        RankId ,
        BrokerName ,
        RankName ,
        BrokerCode ,
        IntroducerCode ,
        CscName ,
        Promotive ,
        NoOfPromotive ,
        PlanTypeName ,
        PlanYear ,
        CscId
ORDER BY PlanTypeName
```

It gives me correct data. Now I want to Insert that data into a table. I have tried like :

```
 INSERT INTO MyTable
    ( BrokerId ,
      RankId ,
      BrokerName ,
      RankName ,
      BrokerCode ,
      IntroducerCode ,
      CscName ,
      SIP ,
      Fresh ,
      FY ,
      SY ,
      TY ,
      Promotive ,
      Total ,
      NoOfPromotive ,
      PlanTypeName ,
      PlanYear ,
      CscId 

    )
    ( SELECT    BrokerId ,
                RankId ,
                BrokerName ,
                RankName ,
                BrokerCode ,
                IntroducerCode ,
                CscName ,
                SUM(SIP) AS 'SIP' ,
                SUM(Fresh) AS 'Fresh' ,
                SUM(FY) AS 'FY' ,
                SUM(SY) AS 'SY' ,
                SUM(TY) AS 'TY' ,
                Promotive ,
                Total = ISNULL(( SUM(SIP) ), 0) + ISNULL(( SUM(Fresh) ), 0)
                + ISNULL(( SUM(FY) ), 0) + ISNULL(( SUM(SY) ), 0)
                + ISNULL(( SUM(TY) ), 0) ,
                NoOfPromotive ,
                PlanTypeName ,
                PlanYear ,
                CscId
      FROM      CTE
      GROUP BY  BrokerId ,
                RankId ,
                BrokerName ,
                RankName ,
                BrokerCode ,
                IntroducerCode ,
                CscName ,
                Promotive ,
                NoOfPromotive ,
                PlanTypeName ,
                PlanYear ,
                CscId
    )
```

But It gives me error. How can I Insert record in table? Thanks.

Comment: "It gives me error" - what error?

Answer (score 11):

Try this one -

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT   ...
    FROM     @tmp
)
INSERT INTO dbo.tbl (....)
SELECT ..
FROM CTE
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: Doh. It's so obvious when you see it.

Answer (score 3):

NOTE:  This has been answered correctly for SQL-Server.  But if you've stumbled upon this post, looking for the same answer but you're using some other DBMS (namely SYBASE, ORACLE, or maybe others), this won't work.  You cannot use the INSERT statement immediately after the CTE.  In these cases, try putting the insert statement first:

```
INSERT INTO someTable (Col1,Col2,Col3)
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT  someColA,
        someColB,
        someColC
FROM    anotherTable
)
SELECT  someColA,
        someColB,
        someColC
FROM    CTE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can insert directly from a cte into a table, here is one such example:

[SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306096/combining-insert-into-and-with-cte)

and another example:

[CTE Insert](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/45c7c5a1-c2da-467e-a431-8ccf800a2abd)

This may or may not help you with the SP, but you could always try a table valued function to return data:

[Table valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

CTE is destroyed as soon as it is used in a query .
After the WITH CTE AS () query , you are doing a SELECT query which returns the data . But after that CTE is not availaible for INSERT query .

You need to do insert immediately after formulating  CTE .

This is from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)

```
A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary result set that is defined 
within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW 
statement. A CTE is similar to a derived table in that it is not stored as an object and lasts 
only for the duration of the query.
```

So this will work .

```
WITH   CTE
      AS ( SELECT   BrokerId ,
                    RankId ,
                    BrokerName ,
                    RankName ,
                    BrokerCode ,
                    IntroducerCode ,
                    CscName ,
                    MAX(SIP) AS SIP ,
                    MAX(Fresh) AS Fresh ,
                    MAX(FY) AS FY ,
                    MAX(SY) AS SY ,
                    MAX(TY) AS TY ,
                    CscId ,
                    Promotive ,
                    NoOfPromotive ,
                    PlanTypeName ,
                    PlanYear
           FROM     @tmp
           GROUP BY BrokerId ,
                    RankId ,
                    BrokerName ,
                    RankName ,
                    BrokerCode ,
                    IntroducerCode ,
                    CscName ,
                    CscId ,
                    Promotive ,
                    NoOfPromotive ,
                    PlanTypeName ,
                    PlanYear
         )
```

Do INSERT immediately now

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
    ( BrokerId ,
      RankId ,
      BrokerName ,
      RankName ,
      BrokerCode ,
      IntroducerCode ,
      CscName ,
      SIP ,
      Fresh ,
      FY ,
      SY ,
      TY ,
      Promotive ,
      Total ,
      NoOfPromotive ,
      PlanTypeName ,
      PlanYear ,
      CscId 

    )
    ( SELECT    BrokerId ,
                RankId ,
                BrokerName ,
                RankName ,
                BrokerCode ,
                IntroducerCode ,
                CscName ,
                SUM(SIP) AS 'SIP' ,
                SUM(Fresh) AS 'Fresh' ,
                SUM(FY) AS 'FY' ,
                SUM(SY) AS 'SY' ,
                SUM(TY) AS 'TY' ,
                Promotive ,
                Total = ISNULL(( SUM(SIP) ), 0) + ISNULL(( SUM(Fresh) ), 0)
                + ISNULL(( SUM(FY) ), 0) + ISNULL(( SUM(SY) ), 0)
                + ISNULL(( SUM(TY) ), 0) ,
                NoOfPromotive ,
                PlanTypeName ,
                PlanYear ,
                CscId
      FROM      CTE
      GROUP BY  BrokerId ,
                RankId ,
                BrokerName ,
                RankName ,
                BrokerCode ,
                IntroducerCode ,
                CscName ,
                Promotive ,
                NoOfPromotive ,
                PlanTypeName ,
                PlanYear ,
                CscId
    )
```

Now you can select data from MyTable

```
Select * from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not perform DML operation on CTE which contains aggregate function.

Check this post. http://adroitjam.com/cte-common-table-expression-insert-update-delete/

Answer (score 0):

Please remove braces for select query after insert query and execute complete code at once

It may work

Answer (score 0):

Declare a temporary table before your common expression table statement and before your select the data from common expression table put a insert statement before selecting the data into that temporary table you've created before.

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
    ( BrokerId int,RankId int,BrokerName varchar,RankName varchar, BrokerCode varchar, IntroducerCode varchar, CscName varchar,SIP int,Fresh int 
     ,FY int,SY int,TY int,Promotive int,Total int,NoOfPromotive int,PlanTypeName int,PlanYear int,CscId int)

WITH [CTE] AS(
    SELECT    BrokerId ,
                RankId ,
                BrokerName ,
                RankName ,
                BrokerCode ,
                IntroducerCode ,
                CscName ,
                SUM(SIP) AS 'SIP' ,
                SUM(Fresh) AS 'Fresh' ,
                SUM(FY) AS 'FY' ,
                SUM(SY) AS 'SY' ,
                SUM(TY) AS 'TY' ,
                Promotive ,
                Total = ISNULL(( SUM(SIP) ), 0) + ISNULL(( SUM(Fresh) ), 0)
                + ISNULL(( SUM(FY) ), 0) + ISNULL(( SUM(SY) ), 0)
                + ISNULL(( SUM(TY) ), 0) ,
                NoOfPromotive ,
                PlanTypeName ,
                PlanYear ,
                CscId
      FROM      CTE
      GROUP BY  BrokerId ,
                RankId ,
                BrokerName ,
                RankName ,
                BrokerCode ,
                IntroducerCode ,
                CscName ,
                Promotive ,
                NoOfPromotive ,
                PlanTypeName ,
                PlanYear ,
                CscId
)
INSERT  INTO @MyTable
SELECT  * FROM [CTE]
SELECT * FROM @MyTable
```