# Store parts as of a cte as temp-tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the following cte

```
with Folders as 
(
    select a, b, c from foo
),
SubFolders as
(
    select 
          x.d
        , x.e 
    from
    (
        select 
              bla as d
            , boo as e
        from
            foobar
    ) x
    group by
        x.d,
        x.e
),
FullTable as
(
    select * from Folders
    cross join Subfolders
)

select * from Fulltable left join Subfolders on ...;

select s.d from Subfolders s; -- obviously does not work
```

(In reality, the cte has more expressions). I would now like query the resultset of `Subfolders` elsewhere in my script. The rest of the cte-expressions I only need once.

What is the most elegant way of doing this (plus: leaving the script as much as is)? I tried what is mentioned in [Combining INSERT INTO and WITH/CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306096/combining-insert-into-and-with-cte) but it gives an error: `The SELECT list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the insert list` even though I am positive that `Subfolders` ahs only 2 columns. What am I doing wrong?

```
.
.
.
),
FullTable as
(
    select * from Folders
    cross join Subfolders
)

insert into #temp (
      Subfolders.d
    , Subfolders.e
)

select * from Fulltable left join Subfolders on ...;

...
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, create separate temporary tables for each CTE.  CTEs only get used once in a query, so you cannot both put them in a `select` query and stored them in a table.

Comment: Nopes cant be done, CTE will always be followed by an Immediate SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE statement, and thats it scope. wont be visible to any following statements also you cannot populate a temp or variable table inside a cte, im afraid you will have to rewrite that cte/part of cte again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way around will be .....

```
SELECT * INTO #SubFolders 
FROM
(   select  x.d
          , x.e 
    from
    (  select bla as d
            , boo as e
        from foobar
    ) x
    group by x.d, x.e
)A



;with Folders as 
(
    select a, b, c from foo
),
FullTable as
(
    select * from Folders
    cross join #SubFolders
)
select * from Fulltable left join #SubFolders on ...;

select s.d from #SubFolders s; -- this will work
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select Subfolders.d , Subfolders.e into #temp from Fulltable left join Subfolders on ...;
```