# Creating #temp before CTE SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to create a #temp table before my list of CTE:s start so that I can use it in the end to perform calculations.

This is what I have written so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

SUM(X+Y) AS Total

INTO #Summary
FROM Table

WITH CTE_START AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM TableX
)
```

....

I have even tried creating my #Summary as a CTE and then writing INTO before FROM. It does not work.

I have looked at similar questions on:[CTE&Temp Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306096/combining-insert-into-and-with-cte)

I have not found anything helpful. How can I create a #temp table before my WITH CTE_START begins processing?

Comment: Why doesn't the code that you have written work? I see no problem with it.

Answer (score 5):

You need to terminate the statement before the CTE with a semicolon, otherwise SQL Server doesn't know the `WITH` isn't part of the previous statement, for example part of a table hint.

For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(X+Y) AS Total INTO #Summary FROM Table;

WITH CTE_START AS ( SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TableX ) 
SELECT * FROM CTE_START
```

Comment: It's a good practice to begin `CTEs` with a semicolon, i.e. `;WITH`. I thought it was worth mentioning that.

Comment: It is funny that I did not use semicolon after the AND line of code. I simply thought it would not work. Sometimes the easier way works better than trying to create additional CTE or #Temp. Thank you. Problem solved.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas - yes, this is a good point. Personally, I find it ugly, as the semicolon really belongs to the previous statement, but this is just a matter of personal taste.

Comment: It's a habit that's [worth getting into](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563.aspx): "Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it will *never* be required :) How could they break 99% of the T-SQL in existence? They still have not even removed the deprecated session options like ansi nulls.

Comment: @usr - and yet they have removed `*=` joins (for any compatibility level beyond 80). It's slow progress but it may happen one day.

Comment: In my experience, MS tend to mark something as deprecated, still support it for 2 or 3 versions, then turn it off by default in the next, and remove it in the version after. We are now seeing things that were deprecated in 2005 (version 9) disappearing: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262%28v=sql.110%29.aspx It's a slow process, but it does happen, and if you don't prepare for it, you may live to regret it!

Comment: All true but breaking 99% of the T-SQL in existence is not on the table. I personally see no reason to insert semicolons except when I'm forced to. I'm not aware of any advantage but it clutters the code a bit. I do the `;WITH` thing, too.

Comment: @usr - I think if this is going to happen, it'll be along the lines of, announced in SQL Server 2014, not implemented until 2 versions later (2018?), then supported as a compatibility level 13 or 14 for another three versions after that, so not likely to cause a real need to change any code for another six or seven years, by which time we're in the year 2025, and we'll all be meat-slaves to the robot overlords anyway.

Comment: @usr - "I'm not aware of any advantage" - it's gets your code closer to standard SQL that requires them. Making any future porting efforts *slightly* easier, but also training *you* to have an easier time if you're working against a different back end (with stricter rules)