# Does SQLScript for SAP HANA support the use of INSERT with CTEs (Common Table Expressions)?

Tags: sql-insert, common-table-expression, hana, hana-sql-script

I know this isn't a specific bit of code or problem, but I am having trouble with a very similar issue to the person asking this (except theirs is for SQL Server): [Combining INSERT INTO and WITH/CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306096/combining-insert-into-and-with-cte) ...and I can't seem to find it out there on any SAP HANA help forums etc. so thought there may be an expert on here who can just give me a simple yes or no answer.

The SQL statement I am using contains **multiple** CTEs, but when I try to insert it tells me there is a Syntax error around the word INSERT. It is definitely laid out exactly the same as in the question I've linked above (spent hours checking), and I can post code samples if necessary but I simply want to know whether it is supported first! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** 
No, CTEs are not supported for INSERT/UPDATE statements.

**Longer answer:**
SQLScript's INSERT/UPDATE commands are actually "borrowed" SQL commands as the  [documentation explains](https://help.sap.com/viewer/de2486ee947e43e684d39702027f8a94/2.0.02/en-US/7a2da744ce544db1814a5fff250e99f6.html).

Checking the documentation for SQL INSERT we find that it [supports a subquery](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/20f7f70975191014a76da70c9181720e.html) as a source of values.

The subquery term is defined as part of the SQL SELECT statement. Checking the [documentation for SELECT](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/20fcf24075191014a89e9dc7b8408b26.html) shows that `<subquery>` and `<with_clause>` are different, non-overlapping terms.

This means, that CTEs cannot be used in subqueries and therefore not be part of the subqueries used in INSERT/UPDATE commands.

You can, however, use SQLScript **table variables** in INSERT statements in your SQLScript blocks, which is very similar to CTEs:

```
DO BEGIN
  te_a := SELECT 10, 'xyz' as VAL from dummy;
  te_b := SELECT 20, 'abc' as VAL from dummy;

  te_all :=     SELECT * from :te_a
      UNION ALL SELECT * from :te_b;

  INSERT INTO VALS 
             (SELECT * from :te_all);

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the CTE into a Sub-Select statement in many cases

You can use following

```
insert into city (city, countryid, citycode)
select
    city, countryid, citycode
from (
    -- CTE Expression as subselect
    select * from city
    -- end (CTE)
) cte
```

Instead of using following valid CTE command combined with INSERT (on SQL Server)

```
with cte as (
    select * from city
)
insert into city (city, countryid, citycode)
select
    city, countryid, citycode
from cte
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I'm aware you can convert them and would normally do so for one or two CTEs - I was just really hoping not to have to as I had about 15 that all refer to each other and it looked like it could get pretty messy. I'm using a Calculation View rather than a static table and INSERT statements to overcome this for now

Answer (score 0):

SAP HANA includes this posibility, the order of the code is different than SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (ID)
 WITH cte1 AS (SELECT 1 AS ID FROM DUMMY)
 SELECT ID FROM cte1;
```