# Bigquery INSERT after WITH AS statement not working

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, common-table-expression

I have a CTE like this:

```
WITH source1 as (
SELECT blah FROM blah
), source2 as (
SELECT moreblah FROM source1)

SELECT * FROM source2;
```

I want to insert the results of this query into a table, but when I write this:

```
WITH source1 as (
SELECT blah FROM blah
), source2 as (
SELECT moreblah FROM source1)

INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM source2;
```

It says I have a syntax error `Expected "(" or "," or keyword SELECT but got keyword INSERT`. I'm wondering if this is a Bigquery issue b/c I've looked at other places like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306096/combining-insert-into-and-with-cte) which say my INSERT INTO should work. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In BigQuery, the `WITH` goes with the `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO newtable 
    WITH source1 as (
          SELECT blah FROM blah
         ),
         source2 as (
          SELECT moreblah FROM source1
         )
    SELECT *
    FROM source2;
```