# Importing from one database to another, with confllicting ID fields

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, import

I have a Ruby on Rails application that has two active environments, `Stage` and `Production`.  Our development team has been using `Stage`, but we would like to move our data onto the production server for various reasons.  However, there are conflicting ID's in the new database, so it's not as simple as pulling the data from one location and inserting it into another.  For example, say we have a table called Widgets:

```
Widget:
  id: 9836
  name: "Staging widget"
  parent_id: 9635
  container_id: 533
```

If the above data is one of our widgets, we can't do the import because there is already a widget with `ID 9836` and/or there is already a container with the `ID 533`, meaning we would need to crawl the association chain to construct new containers before putting widgets in them.

We are using MySQL databases for both environments.  I thought about doing the import, and just adding 10,000 to all the appropriate columns that end in `_id`, as it would push us beyond the conflicting boundaries, but that seems like a bad solution.

Are there any tools, projects, or ideas that may help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't use negative ids simply add a number to all imported ids. The number has to be greater than maximum id from the destination database.

Comment: Will this cause an issue with the MySQL sequence generator when it catches up to those ID's?

Comment: It will not cause any problems. The next value generated by the autoincrement sequence will be max id +1, regardless  if that id was explicitly inserted or generated by autoincrement

Comment: Here is  a fragment from mysql manual detailing autoincrement behavior http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have solved this problem in a kludgy way by making all of the IDs negative for the data I am importing. This only works if your ID column is signed, and there are only two data sources at most, of course.

Comment: MySQL supports using negative ID's for things?

Comment: @Mike: Yes, it does. Your PK int can be signed or unsigned.

Comment: It looks like ours are unsigned, which must be the Rails default when creating tables, as a simple test confirmed it.  I'll see if this solution will work for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, ActiveRecord, our ORM, converts negative integers back to positive whenever saving an entity, meaning this solution won't work for us.  It was a great idea though.

Comment: @Mike: Wow, and it does that transparently? That is plain wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for a way to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you should do (I am assuming this is MySQL based on the tag) is to run the following SQL (I am not a RoRails guy, but a PHP w/ MySQL, so I apolgize if this doesnt apply):

This post id [one basic idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from)

The other option is to use a program like the phpMyAdmin (yes, it is php) which is essentially a database GUI tool.  With phpMyAdmin you can export select fields of the table.  Just export all the data EXCEPT the ID field and then you can just run an import of that data.

This part I am a little fuzzy on.  I think you have an actual file with the Widget stuff in it.  If so, create a script that goes through each row of data and makes the Widget file.

Comment: This won't work, as importing all Widgets won't automatically update their association ID's (foreign keys) to parents and containers.  That's the real issue.  Also, I don't have an actual file with widget data in it, that was a YAML based construction of a database row.

Comment: Can you create a YAML file?  Because if you were to get the data in the DB you could just re-create the YAML file. Perhaps something like: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2525