# SQL: Copying data from 1 table to 3 others

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I've been reading W3 Schools on SQL Insert INTO, which from my understanding creates a backup copy of data into a new table. I have over 300 records to add.

I have 4 tables, one of which is the source I am coping from. 
1) Card Access, which is the source
2) pro_Profile, main dest
3) pro_Email, secondary dest
4) pro_Address, third dest

I have no control over this database schemea. It's too much work to rebuilt everything to work with 1 table then the three. Also the data I am adding maybe a duplicate of what exists, so we need to skip those too.

Card access has these fields:
CSUID which maps to pro_Profile
firstName which maps to pro_Profile
lastName which maps to pro_Profile
eName which maps to pro_Profile
Email Address which maps to pro_Email
Contact Phone Number which maps to pro_Address

Once I copy into Pro_Profile it'll need to get the primary key, profileID which is the reference to the profile accross all these tables.

How do I copy all this data first into the pro_Profile so I can get the unique key profileID which is a forgien key to all the other tables?

Here's my code so far:

```
SELECT
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    eName,
    CSUID
INTO

WHERE NOT EXISTS (
 Select
    firstName,
    LastName 
 From
    pro_Profile 
)
```

New QUERY which affects 0 rows

```
INSERT INTO pro_Profile ("firstName","lastName","userName","departmentID","csuID")
SELECT "First Name","Last Name","eName","Department","CSUID"
FROM "Card Access"
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
 Select
    firstName,
    LastName 
 From
    pro_Profile 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for your insert will be

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1 )
SELECT  col1
FROM    table2
```

So basically you select what you want to insert. You will be able to do it as one statement from all the tables and can add a where clause also. Check out the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from) question also.

UPDATE:
First write your sql query to get the rows you want to insert. So the query you have above:

```
SELECT "First Name","Last Name","eName","Department","CSUID"
FROM "Card Access"
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
 Select
    firstName,
    LastName 
 From
    pro_Profile 
)
```

when ran alone should return all the results you will be inserting. What do you get when you just run that?

UPDATE: I think you are misunderstading not exist. Check out [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html). I think you need something like:

```
SELECT "First Name","Last Name","eName","Department","CSUID"
FROM "Card Access" ca
WHERE (
  Select count(*)
  From pro_Profile 
  WHERE firstName = ca.firstName
    AND LastName = ca.lastName
  ) = 0
```

UPDATE: Or alternatively you should be able to do:

```
SELECT "First Name","Last Name","eName","Department","CSUID"
FROM "Card Access" ca
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
 Select
    firstName,
    LastName 
 From
    pro_Profile 
 WHERE firstName = ca.firstName
   AND LastName = ca.lastName
)
```

Comment: I just tried that and got the message, (0 row(s) affected), it's posted above.

Comment: @jschoen, you need a `WHERE` in your `NOT EXISTS` linking the two tables

Comment: @Brad I think what you are saying would work, but I think the count I just put would work also.

Comment: In my experience, `WHERE NOT EXISTS` is usually considerably faster than any other implementation of an anti-join.  It's a good trick to have in your belt.

Comment: @Jon You are most likely correct. I have just never used it much, so my first thought was to do a count. I added it to my answer and will definitely keep it in mind for my own future reference.

Comment: None of the data gets filtered out. Lets say I have my name in both pro_Profile and the card access, I'll still be inserted as a dup.