# insert data from one table to another

Tags: sql

I have 2 different tables but the columns are named slightly differently.
I want to take information from 1 table and put it into the other table. I need the info from table 1 put into table 2 only when the "info field" in table 1 is not null. Table 2 has a unique id anytime something is created, so anything inserted needs to get the next available id number.

**Table 1**

```
category
clientLastName
clientFirstName
incidentDescription
info field is not null then insert all fields into table 2
```

**Table 2**

```
*need a unique id assigned
client_last_name
client_first_name
taskDescription
category
```

Comment: If you are facing syntax related problem then read this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from

Comment: @Jon I was about to suggest the same thing. OP, what have you tried already?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should work.  You don't need to worry about the identify field in Table2.

```
INSERT INTO Table2
 (client_last_name, client_first_name, taskDescription, category)
 (SELECT clientLastName, clientFirstName, incidentDescription, category
  FROM Table1
  WHERE info_field IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: The difference in names won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Member_ID nvarchar(255) primary key,
Name nvarchar(255),
Address nvarchar(255)
)
insert into Member(Member_ID,Name,Address) (select m.Member_Id,m.Name,m.Address from library_Member m WHERE Member_Id IS NOT NULL)
```