# Populating value in tables SQLITE

Tags: iphone, ios, sql, sqlite

Is there a way to populate a table dynamically from another table?

That is I have  2 table

1. `Customer` which has field `regionName`
2. `Region` which has field `Name`.

**On populating** customer table,it should populate the distinct values of `customer` table  `regionName` into the `Region` table `Name` field **automatically**.

Is it possible? Then how?If not How to populate the value in both table from a single webservices?

Comment: Check similar question: [insert data from one table to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846485/insert-data-from-one-table-to-another)

Comment: Will you make it more clear. please

Comment: Is your query: get all users has a specific region belongs to name in region table

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you mean with "populating".

If you want to do this only once, use a statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO Region(Name) SELECT DISTINCT regionName FROM customer;
```

If you want to do this whenever a new customer is added, you need a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER add_customer_region
AFTER INSERT ON customer
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Region(Name) VALUES(NEW.regionName);
END;
```

This trigger requires a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `Region.Name` column.