# INSERT SELECT statement in Oracle 11G

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to run a very simple sql statement in Oracle 11g.

```
 insert into table1 (col1, col2) values (select t1.col1, t2.col2 from oldtable1 t1, oldtable2 t2);
```

Very simple query. Cartesian join old table 1 to old table 2, put the resulting values into table 1.

I've run the subquery by itself, and it works perfectly.

```
 select t1.col1, t2.col2 from oldtable1 t1, oldtable2 t2
```

When I try to run the full statement, I get the following error:

```
 SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
```

I can't get it to work in MySql either. Something is wrong with my statement, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: The Oracle documentation is comprehensive and online.  You can find the syntax for INSERT statements in the SQL Reference.  Check it out: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#i2126076

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from for database agnostic solution.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Your query should be:

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2) 
select t1.col1, t2.col2 
from oldtable1 t1, oldtable2 t2
```

I.e. without the `VALUES` part.

Answer (score 18):

Get rid of the `values` keyword and the parens. You can see an example [here](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlinsert.html).

This is basic INSERT syntax:

```
INSERT INTO "table_name" ("column1", "column2", ...)
VALUES ("value1", "value2", ...);
```

This is the INSERT SELECT syntax:

```
INSERT INTO "table1" ("column1", "column2", ...)
SELECT "column3", "column4", ...
FROM "table2";
```

Comment: I think the items in the `VALUES` clause need to be in single quotes

Answer (score 9):

You don't need the 'values' clause when using a 'select' as your source.

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2) 
select t1.col1, t2.col2 from oldtable1 t1, oldtable2 t2;
```

Answer (score 1):

for inserting data into table you can write

```
insert into tablename values(column_name1,column_name2,column_name3);
```

but write the `column_name` in the sequence as per sequence in table ...

Answer (score 1):

There is an another option to insert data into table ..

```
insert into tablename values(&column_name1,&column_name2,&column_name3);
```

it will open another window for inserting the data value..