# Insert values from two tables into a third table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table `t1(id)` and table `t2(did, ddept, dname)`. I want to insert in table
`t3(id` from `t1` and `did,ddept,dname` from `t2)`. I am totally stuck at this and need some help.

Comment: is there a relation between t1 and t2 tables?

Comment: No relation beteen t1 and t2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Insert into t3 (Select t1.id, t2.did, t2.ddept, d2.dname from t1 cross join t2)
```

However, without knowing how t1 and t2 relate, you'll get a Cartesian result.  Also assumes column order in T3 is the T1.ID, t2.did, t2.ddept, and d.name...

Previous post found :[INSERT SELECT statement in Oracle 11G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323407/insert-select-statement-in-oracle-11g) shows how to do the proper formatting if orders don't match.