# INSERT INTO USING SELECT IN ORACLE

Tags: oracle

I am trying to insert MULTIPLE rows into a table at a time using select as following

```
insert into myTable values(myTable_Seq.nextval,100,select column1 from anotherTable where column1 not in(10,20));
```

Here my last value is selecting values from another table with a where condition.

I am failing here.It's giving missing expression error.

Can we do like this or is it a must to do a forloop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no shortages of examples on how to do this on stackoverflow (see the answer by Ryan here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323407/insert-select-statement-in-oracle-11g).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the VALUES clause if you are inserting from a SELECT.

```
INSERT INTO mytable
  SELECT mytable_seq.nextval,
         100,
         column1
    FROM anothertable
   WHERE column1 NOT IN (10,
                         20);
```

It is a best practice to list the columns in the destination table.  This allows new ones to be added, that are NULLable, without disturbing existing DML.

```
INSERT INTO mytable
  (col1,
   col2,
   col3)
  SELECT mytable_seq.nextval,
         100,
         column1
    FROM anothertable
   WHERE column1 NOT IN (10,
                         20);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `values` and use the sequence value and the fixed value in the query from `anotherTable`:

```
insert into myTable
select myTable_Seq.nextval,
       100,
       column1
from anotherTable
where column1 not in(10,20)
```