# Massive insertion using value from another table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-insert

is there a simple way to make insert to a table using values from another table?
Lets say I have to fetch the NAME value from T1 and I want to make a hardcoded insertion to another table using that value.
The insertion values should be something like
`INSERT INTO T2 (NAME, AGE, GENDER) VALUES (NAME, 22, 'M')`
Name is fetched from T1, 22 and 'M' are hardcoded in the insert query.

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323407/insert-select-statement-in-oracle-11g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a select in an insert:

```
INSERT INTO T2 (NAME, AGE, GENDER) 
SELECT NAME, 22, 'M' FROM T1
```

Also handy because you can ditch the insert and just run the select to test what you are importing before you do it, and easy to add a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` to make it idempotent.

Comment: TY - I was on mobile and couldn't figure out the formatting :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes . . . `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into t2 (name, age, gender)
   select name, 22, 'M'
   from t1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an insert-select statement, where you select literals for the values you want:

```
INSERT INTO t2
SELECT name, 22, 'M'
FROM   t1
```