# Inserting n rows into a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables.  One table (A) has n rows of data and the other table (B) is empty.  I want to insert n rows into table B, 1 row for each row in table A.  Table B will have a couple of fields from table A in it, including a foreign key from table A.  In the end I want one row in B for each row in A.  How can I write some TSQL to do this?

Comment: Please consider [SQL Insert into … values ( SELECT … FROM … )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TableB (ColA, ColB, ColC)
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC
FROM TableA
```

Pinal Dave has wrote a great article on other alternative methods here:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/

Comment: The problem with this is there are 8 columns and I only want 2 to come from table A and the others are hard coded.

Comment: @SachinKainth: so how is this a problem?? `SELECT ColA, ColB, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 FROM .....`

Comment: I've put this code in a stored procedure and this sp takes a int param called NumInserts.  I want to insert n*NumInsert rows.  So, if n is 10 and NumInserts is 5 I want to run this code 5 * 10 (50) times.  In other words for each row in table A I want to insert 5 rows in B.  How would I do that?

Comment: @Sachin (a) why didn't you include that information in your question in the first place? (b) why did you accept this answer if it didn't do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you need to use something like `SELECT INTO`:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PrimaryKey) row_num
   FROM tableA
)
INSERT INTO Tableb(...)
SELECT ...
FROM CTE
WHERE row_num = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using following query.

```
INSERT INTO B(PriKey, RelationshipWithA, Description)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER(), A.PrimaryKey, A.Description
FROM A
```

If you want a more adequate example, you can provide me with specific tablenames and columns that you wish to enter.