# Dump values from a table to another one in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, dump

Say I have a table called dogs that have the following columns:

```
id, fk_hospital, fk_owner, date, name
```

And I want to create another table that will have the following columns:

```
fk_hospital, fk_owner, fk_dogs, what_type
```

In this second table fk_dogs will be the id of the first table. And what_type by default will be NULL.

So basically, I want to dump from the first table to the second table. The create table of the second table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE dogs_info (
fk_hospital char(4) NOT NULL,
fk_owner char(11) NOT NUL,
fk_dogs int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
what_type tinyint(1) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(fk_hospital, fk_owner, fk_dogs)
)
```

How could I dump the content from the first to the second?  Do I need any server language, like PHP? Or I can do it straight with mysql?

EDIT:  I want to do this by chunks, so first do the dump for a particular fk_hospital and fk_owner, and then for next fk_owner. Can this be done with MySQL too?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO dogs_info SELECT fk_hospital, fk_owner, id, NULL FROM dogs
```

Comment: Perfect. I have edited my question because I would like to this with chunks, because the primary table is really big.

Comment: I think in this case you need multiple querys. You could generate your querys with MySQL and then execute them.

Answer (score 0):

use `INSERT INTO..SELECT` statement

```
INSERT INTO dogs_info(k_hospital, fk_owner, fk_dogs)
SELECT fk_hospital, fk_owner, ID as fk_dogs
FROM dogs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this select and while loop

```
$result = $mysqli->query('select fk_hospital, fk_owner from dogs');
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $mysqli->query('insert into dogs_info ' .
                   '(fk_hospital, fk_owner, fk_dogs) ' .
                   'select fk_hospital, fk_owner, id ' .
                   'from dogs ' .
                   'where fk_hospital = ' . $row['fk_hospital'] .
                   ' and ' . $row['fk_owner']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of PHP .

```
INSERT INTO dogs_info(fk_hospital, fk_owner, fk_dogs)
SELECT fk_hospital,fk_owner,id
FROM dogs
```

See [INSERT INTO ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html)

For inserting in chunks use `ORDER BY` clause

```
 INSERT INTO dogs_info(fk_hospital, fk_owner, fk_dogs)
    SELECT fk_hospital,fk_owner,id
    FROM dogs
    ORDER BY fk_hospital,fk_owner
```

See [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_order_by.asp)