# INSERT INTO table SELECT values FROM other_table not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to drop a table from my database, so I'm following the [official instructions](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q11) for doing that. This is what my code looks like:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // A list of the values I want to preserve
    String contents = Values.KEY_ROWID + ","
            + Values.KEY_NAME + ","
            + Values.COURSE_KEY_TEACHER + ","
            + Values.KEY_DESCRIPTION + ","
            + Values.KEY_ROOM + ","
            + Values.COURSE_KEY_TIMES_OF_DAY + ","
            + Values.COURSE_KEY_COLOR;

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE course_backup("
        + Values.KEY_ROWID + " int, "
        + Values.KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
        + Values.COURSE_KEY_TEACHER + " text not null, "
        + Values.KEY_DESCRIPTION + " text, "
        + Values.KEY_ROOM + " int, "
        + Values.COURSE_KEY_TIMES_OF_DAY + " text, "
        + Values.COURSE_KEY_COLOR + " int not null);");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO course_backup SELECT "
        + contents
        + " FROM course_backup;");
    /*db.execSQL("DROP TABLE " + Values.COURSE_TABLE + ";");
    db.execSQL(Values.COURSE_DATABASE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + Values.COURSE_TABLE + " SELECT "
    + contents + " FROM course_backup");*/
}
```

But when I pull a copy of the database to my computer and look at the course_backup table, it's completely empty. All the columns were created right, but there isn't a single row of data. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting from course_backup, which is the table you just created. Quite reasonably (given that there are no inserts into course_backup in between) this table is empty.

Comment: Hahaha sometimes it really does take a second pair of eyes to spot the obvious. ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're selecting the rows from your empty backup table.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the columns that you'd like to INSERT into. See this related discussion: [Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from). Oh yes, and as the others pointed out, your source and destination are the same empty table.