# Insert with Select and Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, visual-studio-2010

first of all... Before someone comes here and tag it as "duplicated question" please take a better look to my question !

I have an Insert that I was using `Parameters` to pass the values but `only` one field I need to take it's value with a select, look:

```
INSERT INTO chamados (club, project, function, description, priority) (@club, @proj, @func, @description, @pri)";
```

Only the `club` field I need to get from a SELECT query. How Do I do that?

Obs: It's not a duplicate question. All I saw in the others threads, it was showing how to get `all` the values from a select, while I just need one... All the others values i'm passing by parameters/strings . . .

Comment: Do you mean that you need to perform the INSERT and then SELECT the value of the field 'club' back? Does that mean the 'club' field is AUTO_INCREMENTed or populated as a result of a table trigger?

Comment: Travis's answer solves this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from

Comment: No, It's not @Matt. I need the select to `get` the value so I can perform the `insert`... Hope I could be clear. Thanks guys ! for answering me.

Comment: @Ghaleon ok, I think then you have your answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mix the hard-coded variables, and the value from your table in a `select` statement:

```
INSERT INTO chamados (club, project, function, description, priority) 
SELECT club, @proj, @func, @description, @pri
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: I tried... But I fail =\ 
INSERT INTO chamados (clube, projeto, funcionalidade, descricao, prioridade) SELECT clube FROM clubes WHERE clube = @club, @proj, @func, @descricao, @pri)"; Then I Passed all these values using `parameter`

Comment: @Ghaleon Move the `@variables` into your `select` clause.. they should come before your `from`.

Comment: Worked just perfect !! Thanks @Michael Fredrickson ! :D