# php mysql - select all rows from multiple tables then save as array of objects (json)

Tags: php, mysql, json, select, pdo

I have this, which works perfectly:

```
include '../sql.php';
$d = $_POST['forum'] or die('no forum name was given');
$p = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=mydb; charset=utf8', $user, $pw);
$s = $p -> query('SELECT * FROM `_' . $d . '`');
echo json_encode($s -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

In the above example, $d is a string (the name of table I want to get all the results from) and I use it to get all the rows of that table and put it into an array (as an object) so that I can retrieve it client-side.

That code produces something like this:

```
[{"id":"1", "name":"bob"}, {"id":"2", "name":"frank"}]
```

What I'd like to do is make $d an array of table names. Then retrieve all rows from all of those tables like a loop or simply select all of those tables at the same time and return the results.

The result should look like this:

```
[
    [{"id":"1", "name":"bob"}, {"id":"2", "name":"frank"}], //table 1
    [{"id":"1", "color":"red"}, {"id":"2", "color":"blue"}], //table 2
    [{"id":"1", "style":"conservative"}, {"id":"2", "style":"gothic"}], //table 3
]
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Did you check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14931001/select-from-all-tables-mysql)?

Comment: It doesn't look like the author found an acceptable answer there. The table names are dynamic and will change. The table names in that one look static.

Comment: They select all table names in the DB. Nothing static there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
include '../sql.php';
$d = $_POST['tables'] or die('no forum name was given');
$p = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=mydb; charset=utf8', $user, $pw);

$ret = [];
foreach ($d as $t){
    $s = $p->query('SELECT * FROM `_' . $t . '`');
    $ret[$t] = $s -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
echo json_encode($ret);
```