# "insert into" syntax using columns from another table and new values

Tags: mysql

I have a `student` table and a `takes` table. The `takes` table is for courses that students have taken or are currently taking, and has columns:

```
ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade
```

I want to use `ID` from `student` but then for the other 5 columns use:

```
(CS-001, 1, Fall, 2009, NULL)
```

I know how to use `insert into takes select, from, where`, and also `insert into takes values()` But I have not seen anything that mixes data from another table and also new data that I put in. The labs we are doing are supposed to be done all in MySQL queries, using phpMyAdmin.

I am poor at explaining things so I am sorry if this does not make sense. Thank you for your help.

Here is the sort of query I want:

```
insert into takes(ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade)
values(*IDs from student table*, CS-001, 1, Fall, 2009, NULL);
```

Comment: Show your queries. What exactly is the problem? Do you have errors?

Comment: Not sure what to try for a query.
So I have a table 'takes' with columns (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade)

I want to insert rows that use ID from another table but the rest of the columns will be (CS-001, 1, Fall, 2009, NULL)

Comment: Do you need to insert a student and using the inserted ID in a insert query for 'takes'?. You could use set @ var1 = (select col from table where filter) and then use @ var1 in the insert statement

Comment: The student already exists in another table 'student'. I need to take the ID's from that table where dept_name = Comp. Sci. and add those students 'ID's into 'takes' but for the other columns in the newly inserted rows to 'takes' I need to use the values I gave.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should fill up your `takes` table with data from your `student` table, and the static values you want for the rest of the columns:

```
INSERT INTO takes (ID, course_id, sec_id, semester, year, grade)
SELECT      ID, 'CS-001', 1, 'Fall', 2009, NULL
FROM        student
WHERE       dept_name = 'Comp. Sci.';
```

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25969/1563422) for more help.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much. I did not know that SQL would be able to tell the difference between a literal and a field in another table. For example ID being a field from another table and 1 being a literal int. Thanks again.