# how to use results of `select` as argument to `insert into`

Tags: sql, select, sqlite, bulkinsert

I'm hacking on my Zotero database with sqlite3, since the Zotero gui still doesn't support editing multiple records at once.  Current task is finding all items from a particular journal, separating out the ones that don't yet have a value for `journalAbbreviation`, and adding the correct abbreviation.  Here are the relevant tables:

```
fields (fieldID, fieldName, fieldFormatID)
itemData (itemID, fieldID, valueID)
itemDataValues (valueID, value)
```

Here is my query to find all the records I want:

```
SELECT itemData.itemID
FROM fields JOIN itemData JOIN itemDataValues 
WHERE (fields.fieldname IN ('publicationTitle'))  
AND (fields.fieldID = itemData.fieldID) 
AND (itemData.valueID = itemDataValues.valueID) 
AND (itemDataValues.value IN ('The Journal of the Acoustical Society of America'));
```

Now that I have that list of `itemID`s, I want to add a bunch of entries to the `itemData` table.  Schematically I want to do this:

```
INSERT INTO itemData (itemID, fieldID, valueID)
VALUES (A,X,Y),(B,X,Y),(C,X,Y), ... (W,X,Y);
```

where X is the `fieldID` for 'journalAbbreviation' and Y is the `valueID` for 'J. Acoust. Soc. Am.' (I know how to get those values).  How can I write this `INSERT INTO` statement to replace `A`, `B`, `C`, etc with the `itemID`s from my `SELECT` query above?

note: some of the records already have the journal abbreviation in there.  I've only been writing `SQL` for a few days, so I don't know if it will cause problems to try to `INSERT` a record that already exists in the table (I'm assuming it will, based on a vague understanding of primary keys and the fact that the schema section in the `itemData` table includes a line `PRIMARY KEY (itemID, fieldID)`).  So it may be necessary to first exclude those `itemID`s that already have a record in `itemData` that includes X as `fieldID`.

Comment: ...have you tried googling your problem? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263%28v=sql.105%29.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from this is pretty basic syntax as long as you know it's out there.

Comment: @Syn123: I assumed it was out there, and I did google.  As a novice SQL writer, I obviously didn't hit on the right search terms, or didn't recognize the right answer when I saw it.  Everything I found seemed to imply that you had to write out each record of the `INSERT INTO ... VALUES(),(),();` statement separately, which seemed ludicrously inefficient.  So I asked for help.

Comment: If it helps, what I googled to find the above links was: "SQL INSERT INTO SELECT". I google most things related to SQL in a similar manner just because SQL is such a popular technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With little discussion with @drammock, found a query that is working. Main part of this query is `EXCEPT` keyword.

```
INSERT INTO itemData (itemID, fieldID, valueID) 
SELECT itemData.itemID, 25, 8356
FROM fields JOIN itemData JOIN itemDataValues 
WHERE (fields.fieldname IN ('publicationTitle'))  
AND (fields.fieldID = itemData.fieldID) 
AND (itemData.valueID = itemDataValues.valueID) 
AND (itemDataValues.value IN ('The Journal of the Acoustical Society of America'))
EXCEPT SELECT itemData.itemID, 25, 8356
FROM fields JOIN itemData JOIN itemDataValues 
WHERE (fields.fieldname IN ('journalAbbreviation'))  
AND (fields.fieldID = itemData.fieldID) 
AND (itemData.valueID = itemDataValues.valueID) 
AND (itemDataValues.value IN ('J. Acoust. Soc. Am.', 'J Acoust Soc Am'));
```

Comment: use a `DISTINCT` keyword OR **INNER JOIN** to get different set of values. Check the updated query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25550/discussion-between-ravindra-gullapalli-and-drammock)

Comment: explanatory note: 25 is the `fieldID` for "journalAbbreviation" and 8356 is the `valueID` for "J. Acoust. Soc. Am."

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a copy of Ravindra's answer only with `DISTINCT` and my preferred syntax of having the foreign key links in the `FROM` statement simplifying the `WHERE` clause, and in my opinion making it more readable.

I've also added a self join and said `WHERE existing.itemID IS NULL` to avoid inserting records that already exist.

```
INSERT INTO itemData (
  itemID, 
  fieldID, 
  valueID) 
SELECT DISTINCT
  itemData.itemID, 
  'journalAbbreviation', 
  'Journal of the Acoustical Society of America' 
FROM 
  fields 
    INNER JOIN itemData ON fields.fieldID = itemData.fieldID
    INNER JOIN itemDataValues ON itemData.valueID = itemDataValues.valueID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN itemData existing ON itemData.itemID = existing.itemID
WHERE 
  fields.fieldname = 'publicationTitle'
  AND itemDataValues.value = 'The Journal of the Acoustical Society of America'
  AND existing.itemID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do this via Zotero's javascript API, which makes data corruption a lot less likely.
http://www.zotero.org/support/dev/client_coding/javascript_api

Also, if all you're looking for is journal abbreviations, consider running the branch xpi for Zotero's 3.1 branch, which has automatic journal abbreviations via a list from MEDLINE:
http://www.zotero.org/support/dev_builds#zotero_31_branch

Comment: I considered using the API, but I don't know Javascript very well.  Good to know that abbreviations are on the way toward being automatically added though.