# Insert dymamic values in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to insert a new row into database Oracle.

```
INSERT INTO xx_vms.es_supplier_process_steps (process_step_id, supplier_process_id, supplier_step_id,
mapped_item_type, mapped_subinventory_code, mapped_subinventory_type, mapped_operation_code, mapping_notes)
VALUES (xx_vms.seq_es_supplier_proc_step_id.NEXTVAL, xx_vms.seq_es_supplier_proc_id.CURRVAL,
xx_vms.seq_es_supplier_step_id.CURRVAL, 'ASY', null, 'IN', null, null);
```

With xx_vms.seq_es_supplier_proc_id.CURRVAL column is result of this below query. Example: 122:

```
select supplier_process_id from xx_vms.es_supplier_processes where supplier_code='TEST'and name='FINAL TEST';
```

But I don't know how to do this. Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: can you please clarify your question a little more ?

Comment: I would like to replace xx_vms.seq_es_supplier_proc_id.CURRVAL because it's not true. The exact value for this column is the result of 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

you will want to use a subquery for the insert

```
 INSERT INTO xx_vms.es_supplier_process_steps 
      (process_step_id, 
      supplier_process_id, 
      supplier_step_id,
      mapped_item_type, 
      mapped_subinventory_code, 
      mapped_subinventory_type, 
      mapped_operation_code, 
      mapping_notes)
 SELECT x_vms.seq_es_supplier_proc_step_id.NEXTVAL, 
       (select supplier_process_id 
         from xx_vms.es_supplier_processes 
         where supplier_code='TEST'and 
               name='FINAL TEST'),
        xx_vms.seq_es_supplier_step_id.CURRVAL, 
        'ASY', 
        null, 
        'IN', 
        null, 
        null
 FROM DUAL);
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand this query.

Comment: I took your query, formatted it, turned it into a select insert (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from) and replaced what you needed to be a query with your query.

Comment: Don't you think 'FROM DUAL' is needed for the SELECT statement? Also, semicolon at the end of the inner sub query is not correct.

Comment: @Noel funny, I added the FROM DUAL as you posted that. Removed the semicolon =)