# Can PreparedStatement.executeUpdate() ever return 0 on INSERT?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Is there any condition under which a SQL INSERT statement executed with the method `executeUpdate` on a `PreparedStatement` object would return 0 without throwing an SQLException?

For example:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO mytable (column1,column2) VALUES (5,6)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
if(preparedStatement.executeUpdate()!=1){
// A strange error has occurred
} else{
// do what ever
}
```

**Why do I ask?** I currently always check to ensure the number of rows returned is equal to 1 but I wonder if that is overkill if it should never return anything but 1.

Comment: I believe an `INSERT INTO Table SELECT FROM Table` on an empty table might return 0.

Comment: Wouldn't that throw an SQL exception first? By empty table do you mean one that doesn't exist?

Comment: No, a table with no rows in it. Like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from

Comment: O I just reread your query/subquery. I didn't see the "SELECT". That makes sense.

Comment: You would have to test it because I don't know. It's also very probable you never use such a query in your application.

Comment: Retrieve the count if this is meaningful to you. Otherwise use a `try-catch`. Even if you were using the `INSERT-SELECT` statement @SotiriosDelimanolis is talking about, how would you know that a return of `0` is incorrect? This seems like a wrong approach to detect an erroneous condition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I tried it and, yes, you can get a `0` return value with an `INSERT` statement. This can happen if you `SELECT * FROM` a table without rows `INTO` another table. For example, say `domain` and `domain2` have the same schema and `domain2` is empty, doing the following

```
Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO domain SELECT * FROM domain2");
System.out.println(ps.executeUpdate());
```

prints `0`.

The only time I've ever used the return value of `executeUpdate` is with a `DELETE` statement on one row to make sure it existed before and was deleted. I don't think you should use it with `INSERT`.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) of the `executeUpdate()` method:

> Returns: either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language
>   (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

0 seems like a perfectly natural result (i.e. not an error).

Comment: The question is: Is there an `INSERT` statement that will result in 0 rows being inserted?

Answer (score 2):

For the example SQL you provided or for any SQL where a single row is to be inserted from parameters, the result would always be 1 if no SQLException occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Read again:

Returns: either (A) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (B) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing