# Insert from select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Based on this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from) I've encountered a problem with insertions.

My `Tests` table contains:

```
TestID    Name
1       test_insert_film
2       test_insert_writer
3       test_insert_location
4       test_delete_film
5       test_delete_writer
6       test_delete_location
```

I want to insert into my `TestTables` the id's of the tests with the following sequence:

```
INSERT INTO TestTables(TestID)
   SELECT TestID
   FROM Tests
```

But I get:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'TableID', table 'FilmS.dbo.TestTables'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

`TestTables` contains 4 columns, one of them being `TestID`. Why isn't this working?

Comment: Go to your designer, and in your column list you must tick the checkbox to allow nulls for the column TableID. This offcourse, if it can allow nulls which only you know...

Comment: You must provide a value for `TableID` (**not** `TestID`) for your table `TestTables` - that's what the error is saying. You're not currently inserting anything into that column ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column *TableID* (!) in your table `TestTables` is not allowed *NULL* values! This column is not in the list of columns to be filled upon the `INSERT`, so the default value assumed is `NULL`. This is why you get the error.

You may need something like:

```
INSERT INTO TestTables(TestID, TableID)
SELECT TestID, '' FROM Tests
```

To fill the `TableID` column with a default value. Maybe also other columns in the `TestTables` table are affected and need to be treated similarly.

---

PS: You could also modify the the `TestTables` definition to provide a default value for the respective columns. If you do so you can leave the  above statement as it is.