# Insert with select statement

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

I have a query that I can't fully understand. I test it with mysql v.5.5 and getting nothing.
here is the snippet:

```
INSERT INTO
            logs (
                f1,
                f2,
                f3,
                f4,
                f5,
                f6
            )
        SELECT
                'test',
                'done',
                'test',
                'test',
                'test',
                'test'
        FROM
            logs
        WHERE
            NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT * FROM
                        logs
            WHERE
                f1 = 'test' and
                f2 = 'done' and
                f3 = 'test' and
                f4 = 'test' and
                f5 = 'test' and
                f6 = 'test'
            )
        LIMIT 1
```

What I understood is that the fields from other tables can be selected and iserted, but what I don't understand is why not fields, but field values are selected. Was this available in former versions of MySQL ? Also.. I need an appropriate query to be ran in SQL Server 2008. Any explanations? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SQL inserts a row in your table `logs` with the values

```
 f1 = 'test' and
 f2 = 'done' and
 f3 = 'test' and
 f4 = 'test' and
 f5 = 'test' and
 f6 = 'test'
```

if that row with that values doesn't exist in the table.

```
INSERT INTO
        logs (
            f1,
            f2,
            f3,
            f4,
            f5,
            f6
        )
        -- Here we're specifying which value will have every field
    SELECT
            'test',
            'done',
            'test',
            'test',
            'test',
            'test'
    FROM
        logs
    WHERE
        -- Here we're looking into the table 'logs' for the row with that values.
        -- If we match the condition we'll insert into the table
        NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM
                    logs
        WHERE
            f1 = 'test' and
            f2 = 'done' and
            f3 = 'test' and
            f4 = 'test' and
            f5 = 'test' and
            f6 = 'test'
        )
    LIMIT 1
```

About the version, from MySQL 5.0 this is available: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html, and even MySQL 4.1: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/insert-select.html

About SQL, I'm sorry, never worked with it, but surely it'll have a similar sentence, you may look into this SO question: [Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from)

Comment: very cool explanation. BTW, I tried to extract just the select .. from (without where) part, and the results are that the values in the select statements are treated as column names.. is this ok?

Comment: If you extract just the select, you're not doing anything. A select of a string is just the string. If you want assign the value as a field, you may do `SELECT 'string' AS f1 `, this will give you a f1 field with 'string' as value

Comment: XD, Ok, try this: `SELECT 'perry' as f1, 'mason' as f2;` this will give you a row with two fields, f1 => perry and f2 => mason, if you added a FROM clause: `SELECT 'perry' as f1, 'mason' as f2 FROM logs;` it wouldn't matter, this will give you the same result because you're not filtering with a `WHERE` in the table you're looking for