# T-SQL Insert Column from Other Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-insert

Hello I am trying to insert values from one table column to another table. I am using **`SQL Server 2008 R2`**. Here is example:

Table 1

```
Declare @Table1 table (file varchar(15), type int, partiesid int)
```

Table 2

```
Declare @Table2 table (file varchar(15), ....many other columns)
```

I would like to insert file from Table 2 into Table 1 as well as some other static values.

So select * from table1 would end up looking like this:

```
File           Type        PartiesID

GW100          1           555
GW101          1           555
GW103          1           555
GW104          1           555
```

where the GW100, GW101, etc come from table2 and the 1 and 555 are static for every row.

I tried insert into table1 (file,type,partiesid) values (select file from table2,1,555) but that doesn't work. Is there a way where it will just insert a row for each unique file and also insert the static fields of 1 and 555 as separate columns?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from)

Comment: Do you have a screen shot of your results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Insert into @table2
(
file,
type,
partiesid,
...(other columns for which you need to give static values)
)
select 
file,
type,
partiesid,
...(static values for columns)
from @table1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below query:

```
USE dbName
GO
INSERT INTO table2 (column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1;
GO
```

Comment: Wouldn't @ have to before the table names?