# How to insert number of records in one table with respect to each of the value of a column i another table

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a table name TABLE1 in which I have a column YEAR where I an storing the year information like 1990 , 2000 ,2001 etc. I have another table TABLE2 in which I have the Year column and other columns as well.

Now I want to select each year from the TABLE1 and then insert some record into the TABLE2 like...

```
Year     Information
1990     abc
1990     lmn
1990     xyz
2000     abc
2000     lmn 
2000     xyz
```

How can I get this I do not know how I will use the while loop or how I will get the each row from select statement and then pass it to the insert statement.

Comment: Use insert with select. EDIT: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from

Comment: But i want to go continuously for each row for Year

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table2 ( Year, OtherColumn )

SELECT      Year
            OtherColumn

FROM        dbo.Table1
```

Of course, you can add whatever `WHERE` or `GROUP BY`, etc. clauses to suit your needs.