# Append table to an existing one: SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table `A` with two columns that I want to append to another table `B`, how can I do that? They have the exact same rows. Software is `SQL Server 2012`.

EDIT (attempted code from comment):

```
INSERT INTO B_table([Column 0], [Column 1])
    SELECT [Column 0], [Column 1]
    FROM [dbo].[A] ;
```

Comment: What are the things you have tries till now???

Comment: INSERT INTO B_table([Column 0], [Column 1]) 
SELECT [Column 0], [Column 1]
 FROM [dbo].[A]

I tried to create the table with empty columns too, but when I put the data, it creates more rows, instead of inserting in NULL columns

Comment: answered, that should work, see the link also for more details.

Comment: @npereira . . . And what is the problem with that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Insert into … values ( SELECT … FROM … )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from).

Comment: "They have the exact same rows".  Do you really mean:  "they have the exact same columns"?

Comment: you´re right, did not see that question. i´ve tried, but it doesn´t recognize columns in insert sentence. column names are invalid.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, they have the same number of rows, number of columns are different.

Comment: Please edit the question to show sample data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The basic form is:

```
insert into tableB(col1, col2)
    select col1, col2
    from tableA;
```

This may not work if, for instance, you have a unique constraint on the columns and the `insert` violates this constraint.

This assumes that you actually want to add the rows to the table.  If you just want to see the results together:

```
select col1, col2 from tableB union all
select col1, col2 from tableA;
```

EDIT:

The goal seems to be to add columns one `tableB`.  You can do this by adding the columns and then updating the values:

```
alter table tableB add col1 . . . ;
alter table tableB add col2 . . . ;
```

The `. . .` is the definition of the column.

Then do:

```
update b
    set col1 = a.col1, col2 = b.col2
    from tableb b join
         tablea a
         on b.joinkey = a.joinkey;
```

If you don't have a column for joining, then you have a problem.  Tables in SQL are inherently unordered, so there is no way to assign values from a particular row of `A` to a particular row of `B`.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 SELECT * FROM tbl2;
```

Comment: This assumes the columns are the same. (I just read in your comment that the numbers of columns are different.)

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable (FirstName, LastName)
SELECT FirstName, LastName
FROM OtherTable
```

Method 2:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName
INTO TestTable
FROM OtherTable
```

[Source](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/).

Answer (score 0):

If the new table does not exist yet, you have to create it first,  or use the form:

`Select [Column list]  Into [NewTableName] From [oldTableName]`,

as in

```
Select col1, col2
Into NewTable
From OldTable
```