# Copy all information from one table and insert it into another table on different server using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to copy everything from a table on my local server and insert it into a table on a remote server.

Something like

```
    INSERT INTO table2
    SELECT * FROM table1;
```

How can I adapt this for 2 tables on different servers and databases?

Comment: Easy method is to Use export/import data in PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: why would you want to use php for this?

Comment: Is this a one time operation or something that must be done repeatedly?  Is it possible for you to use [FEDERATED tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html)?

Comment: I need to update very quickly (at least once per minute) and I don't think that is feasible with export/import.

Edit: tried using Federated tables, but it requires static IP's, I think.

Comment: Sounds like you should explain your use case a little better. copying a whole table every minute seems rather unnecessary in 95% of the cases. Your php code will have to be bootstrapped too by a cron job. In short: Connect to db 1, read everything in memory. Disconnect and connect to DB1, insert into table 2

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to use PHP, then you could do something like querying everything from one table, simply like SELECT * FROM table, and then iterating over your table with a while loop, inserting one record at a time to the new table. I assume you know some PHP, for this answer to help you. You can't do it with one SQL statement atleast, that's for sure.

Comment: Something like phpmyadmin would be easier if you don't know how to export your tables in MySQL.  @Lozzano I know you're just answering the question, I'm not trying to give you a hard time, just hoping OP would reconsider.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this StackOverflow thread: [SQL Insert into … values ( SELECT … FROM … )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from). There are discussed some compatibility issues across various database engines, too.
It should answer your question quite good as long as it is within a single database.

For copies between different database instances have look at backup & restore, export & import mechanisms or at seperate copy scripts in php, python, etc. using either native or ODBC database drivers.