# How to insert data into a SQL Server database in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2010, insert

I'm still new here and even in Visual Studio so I don't fully know all the function in Visual Studio. I'm trying to make the system to check the database first for any existing `staID`, `staName`, `depID`, and `telNo` so that the system will skip the process if the data already exist.

But if there aren't any, the system will record the user input to the database.

Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Partial Class Default2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles Wizard1.FinishButtonClick

        Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; AttachDbFilename= C:\Users\ammaramli\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\Project\App_Data\Database.mdf; Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
        Dim strinsert As String
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand

        strinsert = "INSERT INTO Staff (staID, staName, depID, telNo) values (@staID, @staName, @depID, @telNo)"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(strinsert, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staID", staID.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@staName", staName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@depID", depID.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telNo", telNo.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
        con.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

So my question will be, how can I make it like that? It's been 2 days I'm stuck here.

Comment: Don't use the `AttachDbFileName=` and `UserInstance=true` features anymore - they cause a lot of confusion and grief, and will be removed from SQL Server in a future version anyway - better stay away from it today already! See Aaron Bertrand's excellent blog post [Bad habits : Using AttachDBFileName](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/) for more background info on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from)

Comment: I'm still a student though and the lecture asked me to follow what is in the book so I don't really know much about it. But still I'll keep it in mind about it @marc_s . Just that I want to know how to compare the user input and the data in the database for the staID especially.