# SQL Loop through table by date and sum a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with just a few columns:

```
BUS_DATE      VALUE         EXP_DATE
6/29/2015     60            6/29/2015
6/30/2015     100           6/30/2015
6/30/2015     50            6/30/2015
6/30/2015     25            7/1/2015
7/1/2015      75            7/1/2015
```

I'm just looking how to loop through each [BUS_DATE] in the table and SUM the [VALUE] with some [EXP_DATE] logic

```
FOR EACH @BUS_DATE
     INSERT BUS_DATE, SUM(VALUE) 
     INTO #tmp 
     FROM TABLE 
     WHERE (
           BUS_DATE = @BUS_DATE 
           OR 
          (@BUS_DATE > BUS_DATE AND @BUS_DATE <= EXP_DATE)
          ) 
NEXT
```

Ultimately, I'd like the output to look like this:

```
BUS_DATE     VALUE
6/29/2015    60 
6/30/2015    175
7/1/2015     100
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: no looping cuz just group .

Comment: why is '7/1/2015 = 100' ?

Comment: are you aware that for all the rows in your example, EXP_DATE >= BUS_DATE?  In other words, none of the rows in your example would be excluded.  Also, the 7/1/2015 row should total 75, right?

Comment: I want the 7/1/2015 SUM to include both of these entries because of the EXP_DATE:  
6/30/2015     25            7/1/2015
7/1/2015      75            7/1/2015
This is where the 100 comes from for 7/1/2015

Comment: how about you explain the rules in your question?

Comment: I seem to be struggling to ask it correctly.  I want to loop through each BUS_DATE in table, and SUM the VALUE.  However, there are VALUES that have a later EXP_DATE (expiration_date) that I want to use for each day between that BUS_DATE and EXP_DATE sum.  I've edited the WHERE clause above to I believe what I;m looking for.  thanks again for bearing with me here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand your problem correctly:

you calculate a list of `BUS_DATE` (`SELECT DISTINCT BUS_DATE FROM TABLE`).
each existing `BUS_DATE` will appear once.

you join your original table with that list according your `EXP_DATE` logic.

```
SELECT lst.BUS_DATE
     , val = SUM(VALUE) 
INTO #tmp 
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT BUS_DATE FROM TABLE ) lst
JOIN TABLE dat
  ON ( lst.BUS_DATE = dat.BUS_DATE )
       OR 
     ( lst.BUS_DATE > dat.BUS_DATE AND lst.BUS_DATE <= dat.EXP_DATE )
GROUP BY lst.BUS_DATE
```

Comment: YES!  This worked!  I had to tweek my date operators a little but this JOIN did it for me and returns my results in great time.  Thank you very much for sticking with my issue and helping me figure out a solution!  It's much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT BUS_DATE, SUM(VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY BUS_DATE
```

If you would like to store the results in `#tmp` table, use [insert from select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25969/335858) syntax.

Comment: Thank you but I wish it was this simple.  I need to add EXP_DATE logic to it, so I don't think this would work.  For example, BUS_DATE 7/1/2015 if grouped only has 1 entry in my sample table.  It wouldn't be able to include the BUS_DATE 6/30/2015 entry in it that has an EXP_DATE of 7/1/2015.  Maybe I should have just asked for the EXP_DATE logic to be included to keep everybody from being confused?  thoughts?  thanks so much

Comment: @Jay If there is additional logic, please do include it. If the logic changes the question significantly, consider writing up a separate question, because a big change would render the current answers obsolete. The question should describe what needs to happen in as much details as you can provide, perhaps with a sqlfiddle.com example.

Comment: I just editted my original post so the output I'm looking for should make sense now.  I just want to grab each unique bus_date, sum the value and include other bus_date entries if the exp_date is >= the bus_date.  Please have a look, hopefully this will make more sense.  thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:
This now only sums the values when EXP_DATE > BUS_DATE

```
Select BUS_DATE, Sum(CASE WHEN EXP_DATE >= BUS_DATE THEN VALUE ELSE 0 END) AS [VALUE]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY BUS_DATE
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but I must have led onto the wrong solution.  I've edited my original post.  I don't believe a simple GROUP would work in this case because for some rows with EXP_DATE's in the future I'd like to use for multiple BUS_DATES.  Please have a look if you have time and thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: @Jay I think this is what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT BUS_DATE, SUM(VALUE) FROM tblName Group By BUS_DATE
```

In your case here...

```
SELECT BUS_DATE, SUM(VALUE) INTO #tmp FROM TABLE (where exp_date logic here)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but I must have led onto the wrong solution.  I've edited my original post.  I don't believe a simple GROUP would work in this case because for some rows with EXP_DATE's in the future I'd like to use for multiple BUS_DATES.  Please have a look if you have time and thank you very much in advance!!