# Mysql subquery error 1241

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm new posting here, and I was wondering if you could help me with a piece of mysql code:

```
INSERT INTO  cliente (id_cliente,nombre,apellidop,apellidom,usuario,password,activo) 
VALUES ((SELECT id_usuario,nombre,apellidop,apellidom,usuario,password,activo FROM usuario where id_usuario = 1));
```

It returns `error 1241 (21000) operand should contain 1 column(s)`

It's the same number of columns in the insert than the select, I got no idea what is going on? may be a newbie error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use 'VALUES' when SELECTing into an INSERT.

Instead try;

```
INSERT INTO cliente(id_cliente, nombre, apellidop, apellidom, usuario, password, activo) 
SELECT id_usuario, nombre, apellidop, apellidom, usuario, password, activo 
FROM usuario 
WHERE id_usuario = 1;
```

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26080/539394) link for more information.

Comment: Thank you Ross for the edited question and the answer !

Comment: No problem, enjoy the SQL language and welcome to the SO community.