# Looping through a table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Okay so I have this temp table. It has all the orders which a company needs to ship out. I need to somehow loop through the table and insert the information into 3+ tables.

```
@TempTable Table
(
    OrderID Int
)

Declare @value int = (select count(orderID) from @temptable)
Declare @i int = 1
WHILE @i < @value BEGIN
    Declare @orderid= (select first(orderid) from @temptable)
    INSERT INTO shipment (orderid, Price, Date, DateDue)
    VALUES (@orderid, @Price, @Date, @DateDue);
    Set @i += 1
    Delete top(1) from @temptable
END
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

*Adding a little more to my issue*

I'm taking in 3 values from VB.Net that as an example is @Price, @Date, and @DateDue.Because of this I wasn't able just to do a select statement cause the values are mixed with this passed values.

Comment: You could do that in a single query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from)

Comment: Not only is it inefficient it is also potentially inaccurate. You have a delete top 1 but you don't have an order by. You also are using first but the function in sql server is first_value.

Comment: @blackpluribus After your add some info this become more difficult to understand  what you want. I suggest you read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looping is not efficient. Always try to avoid it. You will need two queries: one for selection and inserting and one for deletion

```
INSERT INTO shipment (orderid, Price, Date, DateDue)
SELECT orderid, @Price, @Date, @DateDue FROM @temptable;

DELETE FROM @temptable;
```

Note also that the `@temptable` has a limited lifetime. Therefore - depending on the situation - deleting it might not be necessary at all.

Comment: Normally I would agree with you but my issue is the other values aren't from the temptable so I can't just select from the temptable.

Comment: Well, if those other values are pararamters, then use parameters. I changed the query accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Do it in a single query

```
INSERT INTO (orderid, -some other value-)
   SELECT orderid, -some other value-
   FROM @temptable
```

Comment: How the fastest plus 1 i ever got

Comment: Does this work if the other values are passed from code?

Comment: Probably yes. But need see a more detail description of what you mean.

Comment: Example :
INSERT INTO (orderid, price)
   SELECT orderid, @price
   FROM #temptable

Comment: That will insert same price to all `temptable` rows. is that what you want?

Comment: I was trying to just pull out the OrderIDs each time to pass it along with 3 other values from outside the table into another preexisting table.

Comment: Yes, that lose me :( I suggest you rewrite the question and explain all the issues regarding the problem. Include some sample date and desire output.