# How to INSERT subquery as column value that returns many rows?

Tags: mysql, sql

**I need to insert mutliple tuples into a table using a subquery as one column value and a static value as the second column value.
How would I go about doing this?**

My SQL knowledge isn't very vast so I was wondering if you guys could clear this up for me.

Here is an invalid query that shows what I'm trying to achieve.

```
INSERT INTO deleted_messages (message_id, account_id) VALUES ((
SELECT message_id FROM messages 
WHERE conversation_id = 23
), 42);
```

The subquery returns a table with multiple "message_id" values (which is what I want).

The results I'm looking for:

```
Table: deleted_messages
id | message_id | account_id
-------------------------
 1 | 25         | 42
 2 | 36         | 42
 3 | 94         | 42
```

Let me know if I need to clarify. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Insert into ... values ( SELECT ... FROM ... )](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `insert . . . select`, no `values`:

```
INSERT INTO deleted_messages (message_id, account_id) 
    SELECT message_id, 42
    FROM messages 
    WHERE conversation_id = 23;
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed. I'll go ahead and brush up on SQL inserts haha. I'll accept this as the answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select your static value from within the subquery as well, like this:

```
INSERT INTO deleted_messages (message_id, account_id) 
SELECT message_id, 42 FROM messages 
WHERE conversation_id = 23;
```