# How to save a Redshift SELECT atribute into a script variable

Tags: bash, postgresql, amazon-redshift, psql

I want to create a script to automate some processes with Redshift. Specifically, I want find an attribute of one of my tables with a SELECT and then use it in a INSERT. My script looks like this:

```
psql -h ... -c "SELECT id_process FROM process WHERE de_process = 'EMR'"
psql -h ... -c "INSERT INTO execution (id_process) values (X);"
```

In the first sentence I get a unique value, the ID I'm looking for, in a format like this:

```
id_proceso
------------
      2
(1 row)
```

Then I would like to use it as the value to insert in the second sentence, substituting the "X, but I don't know how to save into a variable and then reuse the output of the first sentence.

Any suggestion?

P.D. In other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from) it shows how to do it in a unique sentence, but I need to save the value for a future use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check **[`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html)** options, but sample script can be the following:

```
psql -h localhost -d testdb <<EOF
  \out sample.txt
  \pset border 1
  WITH test_data AS ( SELECT 2 AS id_process)
  SELECT id_process FROM test_data;
  \out
EOF
```

Result for `cat sample.txt` will be:

```
 id_process 
------------
          2
(1 row)
```

If you want to get just pure value from `SELECT` statement, consider following params in the example above:

**`\t`**:

> Toggles the display of output column name headings and row count
>   footer. This command is equivalent to **`\pset tuples_only`** and is
>   provided for convenience.

**`\pset format unaligned`**:

> *unaligned* format writes all columns of a row on one line, separated by
>   the currently active field separator. This is useful for creating
>   output that might be intended to be read in by other programs (for
>   example, tab-separated or comma-separated format).

Comment: It worked with "-t". It gives me only the value.
Thans!!!