# what is going wrong in this query?

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

```
public function insrt_into_aprlog($id)
{
    $query = 'insert into log_indent_apval (select id,indent_req_id,item_id,req_qty,approval_qty,approval_status,prod_categry,prod_type from tra_inent_rq_itm_dt where id ='.$id.')';
    $result =   $this->db->query($query);           
    $resultarr = $result->result_array();

}
```

my controller line:

```
$this->outpatient_model->insrt_into_aprlog($indent_id);
```

> error : Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object

even i tried using in codeigniter model `insert_batch();` still no use.

Comment: why are you using `result_array()` to insert data ??

Comment: need to insert multiple lines..

Comment: are you sure about your query .. ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[result_array()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html) is used to generate query result . You are trying to insert data in your table i guess, so you shouldn't use that . Try below code.

```
    public function insrt_into_aprlog($id)
    {
        $query = 'insert into log_indent_apval (select id,indent_req_id,item_id,req_qty,approval_qty,approval_status,prod_categry,prod_type from tra_inent_rq_itm_dt where id ='.$id.')';
return  $this->db->query($query);           

    }
```

Please visit [this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Answer (score 3):

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from)
Look into your query.

```
INSERT INTO table1 ( column1, column2, someInt, someVarChar )
SELECT  table2.column1, table2.column2, 8, 'some string etc.'
FROM    table2
WHERE   table2.ID = 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$query` is being initialized to a string and then is accessed for an object. This is inconsistent for sure.

Answer (score 0):

`$query` is a string, I guess you should use `$result->result_array()`.

Comment: Yeah...i was a mistake i did it still no luck.

Comment: After looking again, I see that you are using an insert query which doesn't give you a result like the ones a select-query does.