# Using the result of a SELECT query as a value in an INSERT query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to use the result of query as the value of a field in an INSERT query? This is what I'd like to achieve but am I going about it the right way?

```
INSERT INTO tblCounts ( CategoryID, GroupID, CountNo )
VALUES (DMAX("CategoryID","tblCategories"), (SELECT GroupID from tblGroups), 0);
```

Comment: How many rows are in tblGroups?

Comment: Similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/sql-insert-into-values-select-from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use this:

```
INSERT INTO tblCounts ( CategoryID, GroupID, CountNo )
select DMAX("CategoryID","tblCategories"), GroupID, 0
from tblGroups;
```

But it seem that `DMAX` is `Access function`, not `MySQL`?

For condition with a CountNo of 3 and CategoryID of 2 you should add where clause to the select query like this:

```
INSERT INTO tblCounts ( CategoryID, GroupID, CountNo )
select DMAX("CategoryID","tblCategories"), GroupID, 0  -- select 2, GroupID, 3 from tblgroups where CategoryID = 2 and CountNo = 3--?
from tblGroups
where CategoryID = 2 and CountNo = 3;
```

Comment: I'm using SQL view in access, apologies for the confusion! This works, but to complicate things a bit more - I also want to add a condition to my query so that only groups with a CountNo of 3 and CategoryID of 2 are appended. How would I add this clause and make reference to `tblCounts`?

Comment: @JLome then you just add `where CategoryID = 2 and CountNo = 3;` to the select subquery. Could you check if that's what you need?