# Insert into select problems c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# program from which I want to execute

```
Insert into table 
   Select * from table2
```

Here's the code I have

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager
                            .ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString2"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    string selectStmt = "INSERT INTO [TestDB].[dbo].[Test] (ID, Name, CreatedDate) " +
                        "SELECT TOP 10 [ID], [Name], [CreatedDate] FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[TempOrig]";

    using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(selectStmt, conn))
    {
        int resultValue = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Console.WriteLine(resultValue.ToString());
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

I do not see any rows being insert to `[TestDB].[dbo].[Test]` and neither there is an error.

I am not sure what is happening.

Thanks
MR

Comment: Are you sue there is data in `TempOrig` table ?

Comment: Another victim of |DataDirectory| shortcut in the connectionstring? What is the value of _resultValue_?

Comment: Debug the program. Is any exception being thrown? If not there is a problem with the SQL code or the Database itself.

Comment: At least put a ";" between the 2 sql command in selectStmt var so you respect sql syntax

Comment: @user2543740 No need. It is a _one_ command actually. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25971/447156

Comment: Is your ID auto incrementing?

Comment: What do you get in `resultValue` after executing your code?

Comment: Does 'TempOrig' table contains something? if yes, then try getting query from 'selectStmt ' variable and execute it directly in SSMS. You might find something

Comment: @user2543740, it's a `insert into .. select from` construct and no need of `;` therefore.

Comment: When I execute "insert into select" in the sql server management studio, 10 rows get inserted into [TestDB].[dbo].[Test]. And also resultValue=0.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you are only inserting rows, Your sql query isn't returning any rows, it is a simple insert.

**But** if you used `OUTPUT` clause with your insert you will be able to see the rows that were inserted.

Another thing to watch out is that a table will be returned by the `OUTPUT` clause in your SQL query, so you cannot use the `int resultValue` variable to capture the results, you will need a DataTable object.

Things to do:

1. Modify the SQL Query to add `OUTPUT` clause.
2. Create a DataTable object.
3. Fill the DataTable object with the result set returned by the insert.
4. Finally read from DataTable object and display on the console.

---

```
string conString = "Server=ServerName;Database=DBName;User Id=UserName;Password =********; ";
string sqlcmd = " INSERT INTO [TestDB].[dbo].[Test] (ID, Name, CreatedDate) "
              + " OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.Name, inserted.CreatedDate "
              + " SELECT TOP 10 [ID], [Name], [CreatedDate] FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[TempOrig] ";

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlcmd, con))
    {
        con.Open();

        // fill in the DataTable object
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (var insertedOutput = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dt.Load(insertedOutput);
        }


        // Read from DataTable object and print on the console
        DataRow[] currentRows = dt.Select(null, null);

        if (currentRows.Length < 1)
            Console.WriteLine("No Current Rows Found");
        else
        {
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                Console.Write("\t{0}", column.ColumnName);

            Console.WriteLine("\t");

            foreach (DataRow row in currentRows)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                    Console.Write("\t{0}", row[column]);

               Console.WriteLine("\t");
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the question

Comment: You have misunderstood the question