# SQL Insert Into Select Statement With 2 Criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

I have tableA, tableB and tableC like the image. TableC assumption is empty. How to insert data into tableC with Insert Into Select statement ?

Data tableC from tableB with contition from tableA.

I can do it with cursor.

[image]

Comment: can u post tables instead of images..

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25971/7036750

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When possible, you should try to avoid using cursors for these types of inserts :)  (think in sets)

Here is 1 way how to do it:

```
insert
into TableC(ColA, ColB, ColC)
select a.ColA, a.ColB, a.ColC
from TableA a
join TableB b on b.ColA = a.ColA and b.ColB = a.ColB
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query.

```
    insert into tablec(cola , colb , colc ) 
    select b.cola, b.colb, a.colc from tableb b, tablea a 
    where a.cola = b.cola and a.colb = b.colb;
```