# How to select data from one table and insert into another table?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have TableA and TableB, TableA contain data @2,@3,@4,@8 and TableB is the table that I want to insert into. How can I select data from TableA and insert into TableB? Currently I need to retrieve data from TableA first and declare variable to store the data then only can insert into TableB.

```
Private Sub btn_save_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_save.Click
    Select Case MessageBox.Show($"Confirm to update?", "Confirm?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes
            For Each dgvrow As DataGridViewRow In dgv_stock.Rows
                With dgvrow
                    If .Cells("Quantity").Value > 0 Then
                        Dim str_type As String = .Cells("Type").Value
                        Dim int_id As Integer = .Cells("stkitm_id").Value
                        Dim int_qty As Integer = .Cells("Quantity").Value
                        Dim str_remark As String = .Cells("Remark").Value
                        Model_Update(str_type, int_id, int_qty)
                        Model_Insert(str_type, int_id, int_qty, str_remark)
                    End If
                End With
            Next
            RefreshDGV()
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Model_Insert(p_type As String, p_id As Integer, p_qty As Integer, p_remark As String)
    Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO stock_history (stkitm_id,stkitm_code,stkitm_name,stkhis_type,stkhis_qty,
                           stkhis_remark,stkhis_onhand,created_by)                              
                           VALUES (@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9)"


    Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", )
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", )
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", )
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", p_type)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@6", p_qty)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@7", p_remark)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@8", )
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@9", g_currUser)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from

Comment: I only see a table `stock_history`. What is the problem? Why dont use a store procedure in db?

Comment: @theduck Thanks for the link, I solved my problem now.