# Insert multiple rows for each of a result set?

Tags: sql

my google-fu is failing me. 
I'm trying to do the following in a more automatic way:

1) select a set of fields from 1 table

```
select ACCT_ID from MASTER_ACCT where CUST_NBR like '%ABC';
```

2) use the results of that in a multiple row insert

```
// for each ACCT_ID in (1)
insert into TOGGLES (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3)
values('abc', '123', ACCT_ID[i]);
```

Is there a way to execute the 2nd statement for ACCT_ID[i] in each of the ACCT_ID results from the 1st statement?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use an [`INSERT INTO...SELECT`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) statement:

```
INSERT INTO toggles (field1, field2, field3)
SELECT 'abc', '123', acct_id
FROM master_acct
WHERE cust_nbr LIKE '%ABC';
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use the below syntax

INSERT INTO target_table[()] SELECT ... FROM ...;

find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from) link for more details.