# insert data from table A (has uniqueidentifier) and b into table c

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table C column names userid (uniqueidentifier), password,email,createdate.
Table A has columns userid(uniqueidentifier),Email,Createdate and Table B has column name Password.

What query should i execute to get the results. ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask] and the guide how to provide a [mcve] carefully and try to edit your post. :)

Comment: SQL Server 2012

Comment: Actually i have old database that have table profile. I want all info from old db to new one which was created in SQL Server. But problem is that i have created two tables in newdb. Table A contains userID (UniqueIdenfier),UserName ,Email etc but Table B has the columns UserID(UniqueIdentifier) and Password.. I want some columns from Table Profile to Table A and Some columns for Table B..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple **join** between your *table A* and *table B* on the Primary key `USER_ID` in a *select statement* inside your *insert script*.

Here is an sample script based on the information you provided:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_C values (
    select A.USER_ID,
        A.PASSWORD,
        B.EMAIL,
        B.CREATED_DATE,
    from TABLE_A A, TABLE_B B 
    where A.USER_ID = B.USER_ID
)
```

You can learn more on how to insert from a selected query [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25969/insert-into-values-select-from)